# How to delete duplicate entries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, unique-constraint, sql-delete

I have to add a unique constraint to an existing table. This is fine except that the table has millions of rows already, and many of the rows violate the unique constraint I need to add.

What is the fastest approach to removing the offending rows? I have an SQL statement which finds the duplicates and deletes them, but it is taking forever to run. Is there another way to solve this problem? Maybe backing up the table, then restoring after the constraint is added?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

For example you could:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp ...
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t;
DROP TABLE t;
ALTER TABLE tmp RENAME TO t;
```

Comment: Can you make it distinct for group of columns. Maybe "SELECT DISTINCT (t.a, t.b, t.c), * FROM t"?

Comment: DISTINCT ON (a, b, c): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/sql-select.html

Comment: easier to type: `CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT ...;`.
Then you don't need to even figure out what the layout of `tmp` is. :)

Comment: This answer is actually not very good for several reasons. @Randal named one. In most cases, especially if you have depending objects like indexes, constraints, views etc., the superior approach is to use an actual [TEMPORARY TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html), [TRUNCATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-truncate.html) the original and re-insert the data.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: the question asked for the fastest approach.  mass import of data into a table with indexes and constraints is going to take ages.  the PostgreSQL manual actually recommends dropping indexes and foreign keys: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/populate.html.  i'd say your downvote is completely off the mark.

Comment: You are right about indexes. Dropping & recreating is much faster. But other depending objects will break or prevent dropping the table altogether - which the OP would find out *after* having made the copy - so much for the "fastest approach". Still, you are right about the downvote. It is unfounded, because it is not a bad answer. It is just not that good. You could have added some pointers about indexes or depending objects or a link to the manual like you did in the comment or *any* kind of explanation. I guess I got frustrated about how people vote. Removed the downvote.

Comment: Could this approach cause cascading deletes on other tables with foreign key references to columns in `t`?

Comment: Use:
 create table X as table Y; -- to copy the table data info from Y to X (new)
Then truncate table X; -- to remove the copied data.
Makes easy to abstract from table columns and details, but not so much efficient.

Answer (score 180):

Some of these approaches seem a little complicated, and I generally do this as:

Given table `table`, want to unique it on (field1, field2) keeping the row with the max field3:

```
DELETE FROM table USING table alias 
  WHERE table.field1 = alias.field1 AND table.field2 = alias.field2 AND
    table.max_field < alias.max_field
```

For example, I have a table, `user_accounts`, and I want to add a unique constraint on email, but I have some duplicates. Say also that I want to keep the most recently created one (max id among duplicates).

```
DELETE FROM user_accounts USING user_accounts ua2
  WHERE user_accounts.email = ua2.email AND user_account.id < ua2.id;
```

- Note - `USING` is not standard SQL, it is a PostgreSQL extension (but a very useful one), but the original question specifically mentions PostgreSQL.

Comment: That second approach is very fast on postgres! Thanks.

Comment: @Tim can you better explain what does `USING` do in postgresql ?

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Even if you don't have a serial column in your table to use for the id comparison, it's worth it to temporarily add one to use this simple approach.

Comment: The `USING` approach is vastly faster than max comparisons. Great answer.

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin Will flipping the less-than (<) operator to greater-than (>) operator leave me with the minimum user_account.id?

Comment: I just checked. The answer is yes, it will. Using less-than (<) leaves you with only the max id, while greater-than (>) leaves you with only the min id, deleting the rest.

Comment: The second approach is much faster if email is indexed. Like 100X faster.

Comment: This approach also works for MySQL, you just have to restate the 2nd 'user_accounts' like this: `DELETE FROM user_accounts USING user_accounts, user_accounts ua2
  WHERE user_accounts.email = ua2.email AND user_account.id < ua2.id;`

Comment: You could also compare records, which is shorter to write: `WHERE (table.field1, table.field2) = (alias.field1, alias.field2)`

Comment: @Shane one can use: `WHERE table1.ctid<table2.ctid` - no need to add serial column

Answer (score 27):

Instead of creating a new table, you can also re-insert unique rows into the same table after truncating it. Do it all **in one transaction**.

This approach is only useful where there are lots of rows to delete from all over the table. For just a few duplicates, use a plain `DELETE`.

You mentioned millions of rows. To make the operation **fast** you want to allocate enough [temporary buffers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-TEMP-BUFFERS) for the session. The setting has to be adjusted *before* any temp buffer is used in your current session. Find out the size of your table:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('tbl'));
```

Set `temp_buffers` at least a bit above that.

```
SET temp_buffers = 200MB;   -- example value

BEGIN;

CREATE TEMP TABLE t_tmp AS  -- retains temp for duration of session
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl  -- DISTINCT folds duplicates
ORDER  BY id;               -- optionally "cluster" data

TRUNCATE tbl;

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT * FROM t_tmp;        -- retains order (implementation detail)

COMMIT;
```

This method can be superior to creating a new table **if** depending objects exist. Views, indexes, foreign keys or other objects referencing the table. [`TRUNCATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) makes you begin with a clean slate anyway (new file in the background) and is *much* faster than `DELETE FROM tbl` with big tables (`DELETE` can actually be faster with small tables).

For big tables, it is regularly *faster* to drop indexes and foreign keys (FK), refill the table and recreate these objects. As far as FK constraints are concerned you have to be certain the new data is valid, of course, or you'll run into exceptions on trying to create the FK.

Note that `TRUNCATE` requires more aggressive locking than `DELETE`. This may be an issue for tables with heavy, concurrent load. But it's still less disruptive than to drop and replace the table completely.

If `TRUNCATE` is not an option or generally for **small to medium tables** there is a similar technique with a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (Postgres **9.1**+):

```
WITH del AS (DELETE FROM tbl RETURNING *)
INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM del;
ORDER  BY id; -- optionally "cluster" data while being at it.
```

Slower for big tables, because `TRUNCATE` is faster there. But may be faster (and simpler!) for small tables.

If you have no depending objects at all, you might create a new table and delete the old one, but you hardly gain anything over this universal approach.

For very big tables that would not fit into **available RAM**, creating a *new* table will be considerably faster. You'll have to weigh this against possible troubles / overhead with depending objects.

Comment: I used this approach too. However, it might be personnal, but my temp table was deleted, and not available after the truncate... Be careful to do those steps if temp table was created successfully and is available.

Comment: @xlash: You can check for existence to make sure, and either use a different name for the temp table or reuse the one in existence .. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: WARNING: Be careful +1 to @xlash -- I have to re-import my data because the temporary table was non-existent after `TRUNCATE`. As Erwin said, be sure to make sure it exists before truncating your table. See @codebykat's answer

Comment: @JordanArseno: I switched to a version without `ON COMMIT DROP`, so that people who miss the part where I wrote "in one transaction" don't lose data. And I added BEGIN / COMMIT to clarify "one transaction".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think This solution is less efficient when there is not that much duplicate to remove from the original table. And it is worst when there is no duplicate at all. Can you provide some improvement for example to avoid truncating when both t_tmp and the original table have same number of rows (=> there where no duplicate). does `DELETE` more suitable for those situations ?

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin: Yes, of course. The suggested procedure only makes sense to delete large portions from a big table.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Your last example is missing an `N` in `DISTINCT` (one character edits are not allowed, at least for me...).

Comment: solution with USING took more than 3 hours on table with 14 million records. This solution with temp_buffers took 13 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

You can use oid or ctid, which is normally a "non-visible" columns in the table:

```
DELETE FROM table
 WHERE ctid NOT IN
  (SELECT MAX(s.ctid)
    FROM table s
    GROUP BY s.column_has_be_distinct);
```

Comment: For deleting *in place*, [`NOT EXISTS` should be considerably faster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17109431/939860): `DELETE FROM tbl t WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl t1 WHERE t1.dist_col = t.dist_col AND t1.ctid > t.ctid)`-- or use any other column or set of columns for sorting to to pick a survivor.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, is the query you provide supposed to use `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: @John: It must be `EXISTS` here. Read it like this: "Delete all rows where any other row exists with the same value in `dist_col` but a bigger `ctid`". The only survivor per group of dupes will be the one with the biggest `ctid`.

Comment: Easiest solution if you have only a few duplicated rows.  Can be used with [`LIMIT`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5171473/812102) if you know the number of duplicates.

Answer (score 19):

The PostgreSQL window function is handy for this problem.

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
              FROM (SELECT id,
                             row_number() over (partition BY column1, column2, column3 ORDER BY id) AS rnum
                     FROM tablename) t
              WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

See *[Deleting duplicates](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates)*.

Comment: And using "ctid" instead of "id", this actually works for fully duplicate rows.

Comment: Great solution. I had to do this for a table with a billion records. I added a WHERE to the inner SELECT to do it in chunks.

Answer (score 9):

Generalized query to delete duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ctid NOT IN (
  SELECT max(ctid) FROM table_name
  GROUP BY column1, [column 2, ...]
);
```

The column `ctid` is a special column available for every table but not visible unless specifically mentioned. The `ctid` column value is considered unique for every row in a table. See [PostgreSQL system columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-system-columns.html) to learn more about `ctid`.

Comment: the only universal answer! Works without self/cartesian JOIN. Worth adding though that it's essential to correctly specify `GROUP BY` clause - this should be the 'uniqueness criteria' that is violated now or if you'd like the key to detect duplicates. If specified wrong it won't work correctly

Answer (score 7):

From [an old postgresql.org mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/37013500.DFF0A64A@manhattanproject.com):

```
create table test ( a text, b text );
```

#### Unique values

```
insert into test values ( 'x', 'y');
insert into test values ( 'x', 'x');
insert into test values ( 'y', 'y' );
insert into test values ( 'y', 'x' );
```

#### Duplicate values

```
insert into test values ( 'x', 'y');
insert into test values ( 'x', 'x');
insert into test values ( 'y', 'y' );
insert into test values ( 'y', 'x' );
```

#### One more double duplicate

```
insert into test values ( 'x', 'y');

select oid, a, b from test;
```

#### Select duplicate rows

```
select o.oid, o.a, o.b from test o
    where exists ( select 'x'
                   from test i
                   where     i.a = o.a
                         and i.b = o.b
                         and i.oid < o.oid
                 );
```

#### Delete duplicate rows

Note: PostgreSQL dosn't support aliases on
the table mentioned in the `from` clause
of a delete.

```
delete from test
    where exists ( select 'x'
                   from test i
                   where     i.a = test.a
                         and i.b = test.b
                         and i.oid < test.oid
             );
```

Comment: Your explanation is very smart ,but you are  missing one point ,In create table specify the oid then only access the oid else error message display

Comment: @Kalanidhi Thanks for your comments regarding improvement of the answer, I will take consideration this point.

Comment: This really came from http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/37013500.DFF0A64A@manhattanproject.com

Comment: You can use the system column 'ctid' if 'oid' gives you an error.

Answer (score 4):

This function removes duplicates without removing indexes and does it to any table.

Usage: `select remove_duplicates('mytable');`

```
---
--- remove_duplicates(tablename) removes duplicate records from a table (convert from set to unique set)
---
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_duplicates(text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  tablename ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _DISTINCT_' || tablename || ' AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' || tablename || ');';
  EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || tablename || ';';
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' (SELECT * FROM _DISTINCT_' || tablename || ');';
  EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE _DISTINCT_' || tablename || ';';
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4):

I just used [Erwin Brandstetter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries/8826879#8826879) successfully to remove duplicates in a join table (a table lacking its own primary IDs), but found that there's one important caveat.

Including `ON COMMIT DROP` means the temporary table will get dropped at the end of the transaction.  For me, that meant the temporary table was **no longer available** by the time I went to insert it!

I just did `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_tmp AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl;` and everything worked fine.

The temporary table does get dropped at the end of the session.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM table
  WHERE something NOT IN
    (SELECT     MAX(s.something)
      FROM      table As s
      GROUP BY  s.this_thing, s.that_thing);
```

Comment: That is what I am currently doing, but it is taking a very long time to run.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if multiple rows in table have the same value in column something?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to decide on which of your "duplicates" you will keep. If all columns are equal, OK, you can delete any of them... But perhaps you want to keep only the most recent, or some other criterion?

The fastest way depends on your answer to the question above, and also on the % of duplicates on the table. If you throw away 50% of your rows, you're better off doing `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM ... ;`, and if you delete 1% of the rows, using DELETE is better.

Also for maintenance operations like this, it's generally good to set `work_mem` to a good chunk of your RAM: run EXPLAIN, check the number N of sorts/hashes, and set work_mem to your RAM / 2 / N. Use lots of RAM; it's good for speed. As long as you only have one concurrent connection...

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one or a few duplicated entries, and they are indeed *duplicated* (that is, they appear twice), you can use the "hidden" `ctid` column, as proposed above, together with `LIMIT`:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE ctid=(SELECT ctid FROM mytable WHERE […] LIMIT 1);
```

This will delete only the first of the selected rows.

Comment: I know it doesn't address OP's issue, who has many duplicated in millions of rows, but it may be helpful anyway.

Comment: This would have to be run once for each duplicate row.  shekwi's answer need only be run once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with PostgreSQL 8.4.  When I ran the proposed code, I found that it was not 
actually removing the duplicates.  In running some tests, I found that adding the 
"DISTINCT ON (duplicate_column_name)" and the "ORDER BY duplicate_column_name" did the trick.  I'm no SQL guru, I found this in the PostgreSQL 8.4 SELECT...DISTINCT doc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_duplicates(text, text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  tablename ALIAS FOR $1;
  duplicate_column ALIAS FOR $2;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _DISTINCT_' || tablename || ' AS (SELECT DISTINCT ON (' || duplicate_column || ') * FROM ' || tablename || ' ORDER BY ' || duplicate_column || ' ASC);';
  EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || tablename || ';';
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' (SELECT * FROM _DISTINCT_' || tablename || ');';
  EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE _DISTINCT_' || tablename || ';';
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works very nicely and is very quick:

```
CREATE INDEX otherTable_idx ON otherTable( colName );
CREATE TABLE newTable AS select DISTINCT ON (colName) col1,colName,col2 FROM otherTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test (col text);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
 ('1'),
 ('2'), ('2'),
 ('3'),
 ('4'), ('4'),
 ('5'),
 ('6'), ('6');
DELETE FROM test
 WHERE ctid in (
   SELECT t.ctid FROM (
     SELECT row_number() over (
               partition BY col
               ORDER BY col
               ) AS rnum,
            ctid FROM test
       ORDER BY col
     ) t
    WHERE t.rnum >1);
```

Comment: I tested it, and it worked; I formatted it for readability. It looks quite sophisticated, but it could use some explanation. How would one change this example for his/her own use case?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
    FROM (SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY column1, column2, column3 ORDER BY id) AS rnum
                 FROM tablename) t
          WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

Delete duplicates by column(s) and keep row with lowest id. The pattern is taken from the [postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates)

Using CTEs you can achieve a more readable version of the above through this

```
WITH duplicate_ids as (
    SELECT id, rnum 
    FROM num_of_rows
    WHERE rnum > 1
),
num_of_rows as (
    SELECT id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY column1, 
                                        column2, 
                                        column3 ORDER BY id) AS rnum
        FROM tablename
)
DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id from duplicate_ids)
```