# How to delete first few records from a table without any criteria in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to delete first 500 records from my table without any condition.

Table definition is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE txn_log
(
  txn_log_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  txn_log_pgm_id character(6)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

I don't have any primary key here. I tried to delete using

```
DELETE FROM txn_log LIMIT 500
```

but it throwing error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LIMIT" LINE 1: DELETE FROM TXN_LOG
>   LIMIT 5000
>                           ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "LIMIT"

Can someone suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: Please define *first* first. (the records with the lowest timestamps?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a fixed number of rows with sorting in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170546/how-do-i-delete-a-fixed-number-of-rows-with-sorting-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to prepare subquery with `LIMIT` as below

```
DELETE FROM txn_log
WHERE txn_log_pgm_id IN (SELECT txn_log_pgm_id
                         FROM txn_log
                         ORDER BY txn_log_timestamp asc
                         LIMIT 500)
```

Comment: unfortunately after i apply this command in production then i lost all my records :(. why did u do that?

Comment: You should never do something like that in production without testing

Answer (score 10):

```
DELETE
FROM txn_log
WHERE ctid IN (
        SELECT ctid
        FROM txn_log
        ORDER BY txn_log_timestamp limit 500
        )
```

As per [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-system-columns.html)

> **ctid**
>    The physical location of the row version within its table. Note
>   that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very
>   quickly, a row's ctid will change each time it is updated or moved by
>   VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier.
>   The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used
>   to identify logical rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here how to do it without condition:

```
DELETE FROM txn_log
WHERE (txn_log_pgm_id,txn_log_timestamp)  IN 
  (
  SELECT txn_log_pgm_id,txn_log_timestamp
  FROM txn_log
  LIMIT 500
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ctid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393516/724039) (2nd most popular) is the best imo  (most bullet-proof). The most upvoted approach can give  lot of troubles as it did to me (especially in PK-less tables).

If someone prefers more imperative way PL/pgSQL block structure with LOOP can be used like this. Expect lower performance than single query, though.

```sql
do $$        
declare rows_to_delete integer := 2;
begin
   for i in 1..rows_to_delete loop
        delete from txn_log where ctid in (select min(CTID) from txn_log);
        raise notice 'Iteration % finished',i;
   end loop;
end; $$
```