# How to delete certain amount of last rows in the table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Without referencing the SERIAL id.

Something like:

```
delete from users LAST 3
```

which would delete last 3 rows from the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a fixed number of rows with sorting in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170546/how-do-i-delete-a-fixed-number-of-rows-with-sorting-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 11):

This will work :

```
  DELETE
  FROM users 
  WHERE id in (
      SELECT id 
      FROM users 
      ORDER BY id desc
      LIMIT 3
     )
```

Comment: This uses the id column.

Comment: @Eduard Which other column do you have in your table that can track the last/most recent rows you have added to the table ? (Note that postgresql itself does not track this information)