# How thread-safe is the SQL operation DELETE FROM my_table WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM my_table WHERE some_condition)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

#### Motivation

I am using a database table as a persistent queue. The purpose is to implement a **pop operation** on a queue: take any record fulfilling a condition from the queue, remove it from the queue, and process it. The whole procedure is run within a transaction, so if anything fails, the database performs a rollback so the record is not lost.

#### My Implementation

Following the answers to [How do I delete a fixed number of rows with sorting in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5170546/2886891), I am using the following SQL code (in Postgres).

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table 
WHERE ctid IN (
    SELECT ctid FROM my_table 
    WHERE some_condition
    LIMIT 1
)
RETURNING *
```

The same code can be run in parallel in multiple threads, or even in multiple Kubernetes pods, on the same database.

*Please notice that I cannot use just simply `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE some_condition`, as Postgres unfortunately does not support the `LIMIT` clause for `DELETE` and `UPDATE`.*

#### Problem Statement

I am wondering, if the construct `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM my_table WHERE some_condition)` is "atomic enough" in Postgres SQL, i.e. if it is thread-safe, or if there can be situations that two threads start fighting for the same record.

I am considering the following fix, but I am not sure if it is necessary, or maybe if there is something even better to reach the same goal:

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table 
WHERE ctid IN (
    SELECT ctid FROM my_table 
    WHERE some_condition
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE
    SKIP LOCKED
)
RETURNING *
```

Comment: A table level lock would seem to be what you need here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not sure what this mean in the terms of the SQL code :)
If you mean to lock the whole table, no, I cannot afford it!

Comment: This is what "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED" was invented for.

Comment: @jjanes To be honest, now I cannot see why I couldn't see it before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following answers:

- [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11532550/2886891)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/69471/55104
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214443/55104

The result is that in the concurrent setup the `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` clause is necessary to avoid clashes between the threads.