# Delete duplicate rows from small table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in a PostgreSQL 8.3.8 database, which has no keys/constraints on it, and has multiple rows with exactly the same values.

I would like to remove all duplicates and keep only 1 copy of each row.

There is one column in particular (named "key") which may be used to identify duplicates, i.e. there should only exist one entry for each distinct "key".

How can I do this? (Ideally, with a single SQL command.)
Speed is not a problem in this case (there are only a few rows).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM dupes a
WHERE a.ctid <> (SELECT min(b.ctid)
                 FROM   dupes b
                 WHERE  a.key = b.key);
```

Comment: Don't use it, it is too slow!

Comment: While this solution definitely works, @rapimo 's [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12963112/1156554) executes much faster.  I believe this has to do with the inner select statement here getting executed N times (for all N rows in the dupes table) rather than the grouping that's going on in the other solution.

Comment: For huge tables (several million records) this one actually fits in memory, unlike @rapimo's solution. So in those cases this is the faster one (no swapping).

Comment: Adding explanation: it works because ctid is a special postgres column indicating the physical location of the row. You can use this as a unique id even if your table does not possess a unique id. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/ddl-system-columns.html

Comment: @PawełMalisak I read it after I ran it.

Answer (score 322):

A faster solution is to:

- find the first occurence of the duplicate,
- then remove all rows that are not the first duplicate occurence.

This looks like the following:

```sql
DELETE FROM dups a USING (
    SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, key
    FROM dups 
    GROUP BY key HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b
WHERE a.key = b.key 
AND a.ctid <> b.ctid
```

Notice that whith this solution you don't have control over which row is kept.

### Toy example

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
    name    varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    surname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    age     integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO people (name, surname, age) VALUES 
    ('A.', 'Tom', 30),
    ('A.', 'Tom', 10),
    ('B.', 'Tom', 20),
    ('B', 'Chris', 20);

-- The inner command to find duplicates first occurences:
SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, name, surname
FROM people 
GROUP BY (name, surname) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;


DELETE FROM people a USING (
    SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, name, surname
    FROM people 
    GROUP BY (name, surname) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b
WHERE a.name = b.name
AND a.surname = b.surname
AND a.ctid <> b.ctid;

SELECT * FROM people;
```

The inner request outputs:

| ctid | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (0,1) | A. | Tom |

And the final request (after deletion) outputs:

| name | surname | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A. | Tom | 30 |
| B. | Tom | 20 |
| B | Chris | 20 |

[View the toy example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/8761)

Comment: Why is it faster than a_horse_with_no_name's solution?

Comment: This is faster because this runs only 2 queries. First one to select all the duplicates, then one to delete all items from the table.

The query by @a_horse_with_no_name does a query to see if it matches any other for every single item in the table.

Comment: what is `ctid`?

Comment: from docs: ctid. The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's ctid will change each time it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier.

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work when having more than 2 duplicate rows, because it deletes only one duplicate at time.

Comment: @Daria, you're wrong. The query deletes all of the duplicate records which ctid is not the min(citid) for each key. A simple test can prove it.  `create table t_location (country text,city text);
insert into t_location values ('Country', 'City1'), ('Country','City2'),('Country','City3'); --repeat several times
delete from t_location a using (
      select min(ctid) as ctid, city
        from t_location 
        group by city having count(*) > 1
      ) b
where a.city = b.city 
and a.ctid <> b.ctid; select * from t_location order by city; --only 3 records`

Comment: where can I find more information about that using clause? I've seen in joins but not in a way like that

Comment: what if there's no primary key or unique identifier? would this work?

Comment: @Enrique it's just a [PostgreSQL extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) to allow joins for DELETE.

Comment: @FrankieDrake it does work when having more than 2 duplicates

Comment: For UUIDs this doesn't work but you can cast the IDs to text: `MIN(ctid::text)` and `AND a.ctid::text <> b.ctid`.

Answer (score 105):

This is fast and concise:

```
DELETE FROM dupes T1
    USING   dupes T2
WHERE   T1.ctid < T2.ctid  -- delete the older versions
    AND T1.key  = T2.key;  -- add more columns if needed
```

See also my answer at [How to delete duplicate rows without unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46775289/968244) which includes more information.

Comment: what does ct stand for? count?

Comment: @trthhrtz `ctid` points to the physical location of the record in the table. Contrary to what I wrote at the time in the comment, using the less than operator does not necessarily point to the older version as the ct can wrap around and a value with a lower ctid might actually be newer.

Comment: Just FYI, I tried this solution, and aborted it after waiting 15 minutes. Tried rapimo's solution and it completed in about 10 seconds (deleted ~700,000 rows).

Comment: @Patrick can't imagine if your db doesn't have a unique identifier as rapimo's answer doesn't work in that case.

Comment: @isapir I am just curious, the answers above, they are keeping the older records right as they selected `min(ctid)`? whereas yours are keeping the newer ones? thanks!

Comment: @stucash it doesn't make a difference if it's really a duplicate.  You can flip the `<` to `>` if you want.  Also, `ctid` does not guarantee that one is older or newer as it might wrap around.

Comment: same as @isapir -> `ctid points to the physical location of the record in the table` not the the older version!

Answer (score 35):

[**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) is simple and among the fastest for most data distributions:

```sql
DELETE FROM dupes d
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM dupes
   WHERE  key = d.key
   AND    ctid < d.ctid
   );
```

*From each set of duplicate rows (defined by identical `key`), this keeps the one row with the minimum `ctid`.*

Result is identical to the [currently accepted answer by a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6584134/939860). Just ***faster***, because `EXISTS` can stop evaluating as soon as the first offending row is found, while the alternative with `min()` has to consider *all* rows per group to compute the minimum. Speed is of no concern to *this* question, but why not take it?

You may want to add a [**`UNIQUE` constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) after cleaning up, to prevent duplicates from creeping back in:

```
ALTER TABLE dupes ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name_here UNIQUE (key);
```

About the system column **`ctid`**:

- [Is the system column “ctid” legitimate for identifying rows to delete?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214443/3684)

If there is any other column defined `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column in the table (like a `PRIMARY KEY`) then, by all means, use it instead of `ctid`.

If `key` can be **`NULL`** and you only want one of those, too, use [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) instead of `=`. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

As that's slower, you might instead run the above query as is, and this *in addition*:

```sql
DELETE FROM dupes d
WHERE  key IS NULL
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM dupes
   WHERE  key IS NULL
   AND    ctid < d.ctid
   );
```

And consider:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

For small tables, **indexes** generally do not help performance. And we need not look further.

For **big tables** and *few* duplicates, an existing index on `(key)` can help (a lot).

For **mostly duplicates**, an index may add more cost than benefit, as it has to be kept up to date concurrently. Finding duplicates without index becomes faster anyway because there are so many and `EXISTS` only needs to find one. But consider a **completely different approach** if you can afford it (i.e. concurrent access allows it): Write the few surviving rows to a new table. That also removes table (and index) bloat in the process. See:

- [How to delete duplicate entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries)

Answer (score 26):

I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
              FROM (SELECT id,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY column1, column2, column3 ORDER BY id) AS rnum
                     FROM tablename) t
              WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

provided by Postgres wiki:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates

Comment: Any idea of the performance compared to @rapimo's answer and the accepted one(@a_horse_with_no_name)?

Comment: This one won't work if, like the questions states, _all_ columns are identical, the `id` included.

Comment: This query will delete both original copy and the duplicates. the question is about retaining at least one row.

Comment: @pyBomb wrong, it will keep the first `id` where column1...3 are duplicate

Comment: As of postgresql 12, this is BY FAR the fastest solution (against 300 million rows). I just tested everything proposed in this question, including the accepted answer, and this "official" solution is actually the fastest and meets all requirements from OP (and mine)

Comment: this work like i want and the fastest among the current answers

Comment: This is the best solution for this.

Comment: This is my go-to `partition by` example, I keep coming back here every few weeks. :D

Answer (score 10):

I would use a temporary table:

```
create table tab_temp as
select distinct f1, f2, f3, fn
  from tab;
```

Then, delete `tab` and rename `tab_temp` into `tab`.

Comment: This approach doesn't account for triggers, indexes, and statistics. Certainly you could add them, but it adds a lot more work too.

Comment: Not everyone needs that. This approach is extremely fast and worked much better than the rest on 200k emails (varchar 250) without indexes.

Comment: Full code:
`DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TABLE tmp as 
(
    SELECT * from (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM your_table) as t
);
DELETE from your_table;
INSERT INTO your_table 
SELECT * from tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp;`

Answer (score 9):

I had to  create my own version. Version written by @a_horse_with_no_name is way too slow on my table (21M rows). And @rapimo simply doesn't delete dups.

Here is what I use on PostgreSQL 9.5

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE ctid IN (
  SELECT unnest(array_remove(all_ctids, actid))
  FROM (
         SELECT
           min(b.ctid)     AS actid,
           array_agg(ctid) AS all_ctids
         FROM your_table b
         GROUP BY key1, key2, key3, key4
         HAVING count(*) > 1) c);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach (works only if you have any unique field like `id` in your table) to find all unique ids by columns and remove other ids that are not in unique list

```sql
DELETE
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (username, email) id FROM users);
```

Comment: The thing is, in my question the tables had no unique ids; the "duplicates" were multiple rows with exactly the same values on all columns.

Comment: Right, I added some notes

Answer (score 3):

Postgresql has windows function, you can use rank() to archive your goal, sample:

```
WITH ranked as (
    SELECT
        id, column1,
        "rank" () OVER (
            PARTITION BY column1
            order by column1 asc
        ) AS r
    FROM
        table1
) 
delete from table1 t1
using ranked
where t1.id = ranked.id and ranked.r > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
WITH
  u AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM your_table),
  x AS (DELETE FROM your_table)
INSERT INTO your_table SELECT * FROM u;
```

I had been concerned about execution order, would the DELETE happen before the SELECT DISTINCT, but it works fine for me.
And has the added bonus of not needing any knowledge about the table structure.

Comment: The only drawback is, that if you have data type that don't support equality (e.g. `json`) this won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution [using `PARTITION BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) and the [virtual `ctid` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html), which is works like a primary key, at least within a single session:

```sql
DELETE FROM dups
USING (
  SELECT
    ctid,
    (
      ctid != min(ctid) OVER (PARTITION BY key_column1, key_column2 [...])
    ) AS is_duplicate
  FROM dups 
) dups_find_duplicates
WHERE dups.ctid == dups_find_duplicates.ctid
AND dups_find_duplicates.is_duplicate
```

A subquery is used to mark all rows as duplicates or not, based on whether they share the same "key columns", but not the same `ctid`, as the "first" one found in the "partition" of rows sharing the same keys.

In other words, "first" is defined as:

- `min(ctid) OVER (PARTITION BY key_column1, key_column2 [...])`

Then, all rows where `is_duplicate` is true are deleted by their `ctid`.

From the documentation, [`ctid` represents](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) (**emphasis** mine):

> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to **locate the row version very quickly**, a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. A primary key should be used to identify logical rows.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, that worked for me.

```
delete from table_name a using table_name b
where a.id < b.id
  and a.column1 = b.column1;
```

Answer (score 1):

well, none of this solution would work if the id is duplicated which is my use case, then the solution is simple:

```
myTable:
id  name
0   value
0   value
0   value
1   value1
1   value1

create dedupMyTable as select distinct * from myTable;
delete from myTable;
insert into myTable select * from dedupMyTable;

select * from myTable;
id  name
0   value
1   value1
```

well you shouldn't have duplicates id into your table unless it doesn't have PK constraints or simply doesn't support it such as Hive/data lake tables

Better pay attention when loading your data to avoid dups over ID's

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM tracking_order 
WHERE 
    mvd_id IN (---column you need to remove duplicate
        SELECT 
            mvd_id 
        FROM (
            SELECT                         
                mvd_id,thoi_gian_gui,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY mvd_id
                    ORDER BY thoi_gian_gui desc) AS row_num
            FROM 
                tracking_order
        ) s_alias
        WHERE row_num > 1)
    AND thoi_gian_gui in ( --column you used to compare to delete duplicates, eg last update time
        SELECT 
                thoi_gian_gui 
        FROM (
            SELECT                         
                thoi_gian_gui,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY mvd_id
                    ORDER BY thoi_gian_gui desc) AS row_num
            FROM 
                tracking_order
        ) s_alias
        WHERE row_num > 1)
```

My code, I remove all duplicates 7800445 row and keep only 1 copy of each row with 7 min 28 secs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46jJX.png)

Answer (score -1):

This worked well for me.  I had a table, terms, that contained duplicate values.  Ran a query to populate a temp table with all of the duplicate rows.  Then I ran the a delete statement with those ids in the temp table.  value is the column that contained the duplicates.

```
        CREATE TEMP TABLE dupids AS
        select id from (
                    select value, id, row_number() 
over (partition by value order by value) 
    as rownum from terms
                  ) tmp
                  where rownum >= 2;

delete from [table] where id in (select id from dupids)
```