# How to add a conditional unique index on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, null, indexing

I have a `line_items` table with following columns:

```
product_id
variant_id
```

`variant_id` is nullable.

Here is the condition:

- If `variant_id` is NULL then `product_id` should be unique.
- If `variant_id` has a value then combination of `product_id` and `variant_id` should be unique.

Is that possible in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Create a [`UNIQUE` multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(product_id, variant_id)`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX line_items_prod_var_idx ON line_items (product_id, variant_id);
```

However, this allows multiple entries of `(1, null)` for `(product_id, variant_id)` by default, because `null` values are not considered to be distinct values.
To make up for that, additionally create a [partial `UNIQUE` index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) on `product_id`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX line_items_prod_var_null_idx ON line_items (product_id)
WHERE variant_id IS NULL;
```

This way you can enter `(1,2)`, `(1,3)` and `(1, null)`, but neither of them a second time. Also speeds up queries with conditions on one or both column.

**Or** use the **`NULLS NOT DISTINCT`** clause in **Postgres 15** or later. See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)
- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9760/3684)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use expressions in your key fields. This may not have been around when you asked the question, but could be helpful for others that come across this now.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX line_items_prod_id_var_id_idx
ON line_items ( product_id, (coalesce(variant_id, 0)) );
```

Granted, this assumes that your `variant_id` is an auto-incrementing integer that started at 1. Also note the parentheses around the expression. Per the docs, they are required.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createindex.html

Answer (score 0):

Following should work as well -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX line_items_prod_var_idx ON line_items (product_id, coalesce(variant_id,'default'));
```

More about coalesce - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-conditional.html