# Create a multicolumn index to enforce uniqueness

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, indexing, unique-index

I've got two fields in my table that if they(tat and dim) are equal I'm discarding them i.e

```
id| tat | dim | visible
1 | 11  | 22  | true
2 | 11  | 22  | false
```

This is considered not to be valid entry for ids `1` and `2` . Because I want to allow one `dim` per `tat`. So I have a script that cleaned these duplicates for me and after that I added index on this table to prevent this from happening like this :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dim_tat_idx
ON predictions (tat, dim);
```

As explained quite nicely in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8918141/169277

Now going further in this case

```
This way you can enter (1,2), (1,3) and (1, NULL)
but neither of them a second time
```

What type of index would I create or what other mechanism would I use at the database level to allow entering `1, NULL` combination but prevent `(1,2)` and `(1,3)` more times?

Comment: You can add more than one rows with `(1,NULL)` with the unique index you have.

Comment: The question you have linked, provides how to change this (default and standard) behaviour and disallow more than one row with NULL.

Comment: @ypercube how can I do that can you answer ?

Comment: Check this **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ce541/1)**. Is that ok? I don't see where the problem is really.

Comment: I would like you to post some answer because the index wasn't the issue here, this issue I was having is that my values which I inserted weren't actually NULL but rather they were empty string so I feel if I delete this question someone else might be stripped of useful info if you agree reply that is .. thanks though

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow, you can answer yourself, I think will be most appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a misunderstanding.

Your quote from my answer is a bit misleading, since it only applies if you also create the additional partial index as described over there:
[How to add a conditional unique index on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917065/how-to-add-a-conditional-unique-index-on-postgresql/8918141#8918141)

If you do not add this second index (like you did not), *you already have your solution*, it would seem. With the multicolumn unique index alone, you can enter `(1, NULL)` multiple times, but `(1,2)` or `(1,3)` only once.

#### Empty strings

If, by mistake, you were considering empty strings (`''`) (for a [character type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html)) instead of `NULL` values: those are handled like any other value. You *could* deal with this situation using a **multicolumn, partly functional unique index** ([index on an expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html)):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX predictions _dim_tat_uni_idx
ON predictions (tat, NULLIF(dim, ''));
```

This way you can enter `(1, 'a')`, `(1, 'b')` only once.
But `(1, NULL)` and `(1, '')` multiple times.

#### Side effects

The index would still fully support plain queries on the first column (`tat`).
But queries on both columns would have to match the expression to utilize the full potential. This would be faster, even if it doesn't seem to make sense:

```
SELECT * FROM predictions
WHERE  tat = 1
AND    NULLIF(dim, '') = 'foo';
```

.. than this:

```
SELECT * FROM predictions
WHERE  tat = 1
AND    dim = 'foo';
```

.. because the first query can use both index columns. Result would be the same (except when searching for `''` or `NULL`). [Details in this related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql).