# How to allow NULL value for one column in unique index on multiple columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, unique-constraint

Seems like a pretty straightforward question, but I can't seem to locate the specific answer anywhere online.

I have a `price` model that references both quote and a line item, thus it has `quote_id` and `line_item_id` columns. I am using a multicolumn index with `unique: true` to prevent multiple prices for the same line_item from being attached to a quote. `quote_id` is the first column in the index.

However, I want to allow users to add prices to `line_items` that haven't been quoted. It works fine for one price, `quote_id` is null and `line_item_id` is present. However, the unique index is preventing me from attaching a second price to the same `line_item`. The null value in `quote_id` is being treated as unique.

Is there any way to make the unique constraint only apply when the quote is not null?
I know that `allow_nil` can be used in model validation, but can it be used in the index?

I am thinking something like:

```
add_index :prices, [:quote_id, :line_item_id], :unique => true, :allow_nil => true
```

PostgreSQL and Rails 4.

Comment: Thank you for the link - not sure how I missed that question.  So it appears that I don't need the :allow_nil, but the problem is in the order of the columns.  If I place :line_item_id before :quote_id in the index, it should allow what i am looking for, which is multiple identical line_item_ids with NULL for quote_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to make the unique constraint only apply when the quote is not null?

Actually, this is the ***only* way**. You can have multiple "identical" entries with one or more of the columns in a multicolumn index being `NULL`, because Postgres does not consider two `NULL` values identical for this purpose (like in most contexts).

The sequence of columns in the index doesn't matter for this. ([It matters for other purposes, though.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/7484#7484))

Make sure the underlying columns in the table itself can be `NULL`. (Sometimes confused with the empty string `''`.)

After re-reading your question, the more appropriate scenario seems to be this related answer:
[Create a multicolumn index to enforce uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915759/create-a-multicolumn-index-to-enforce-uniqueness/18918746#18918746)
This one may be of help, too, but the question asks for the *opposite* of yours:
[How to add a conditional unique index on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917065/how-to-add-a-conditional-unique-index-on-postgresql)

**If** you actually want a [**partial index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) with only non-null value, you *can* do that too:

```
CREATE INDEX price_uni_idx ON price (quote_id, line_item_id)
WHERE  quote_id     IS NOT NULL
AND    line_item_id IS NOT NULL;
```

You do not *need* that for your purpose, though. It may still be useful to exclude rows with NULL values from the index to make it faster. Details here:
[Indexed ORDER BY with LIMIT 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833832/indexed-order-by-with-limit-1/18834122#18834122)

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly the answer I needed.  I was able to get it to work properly.