# Unique index in one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, unique-index

I have a table, with the columns `login`, `lineno`,  `line`.
Each `login` can have 3 `lineno` and 3 `lines`, each `lineno` has to be unique if the `login` is the same.

I've tried:

```
create unique index unique_Lineno on rs_line (Lineno) where login=login;
```

It doesn't work. Can anyone please give me some help?
I've read the http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-unique.html but there is no sample.

Comment: Your tag was wrong. [psql](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/psql/info) is the comman line client of Postgres. You want Postgres. Also please have a look at formatting options ...

Answer (score 1):

Your condition for the [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html): `login=login` doesn't do what you seem to be expecting. It *always* evaluates to `TRUE`, if `login is NOT NULL`, which is not helping at all for your case.

You need a [**multicolumn index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) instead:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX rs_line_uni_idx ON rs_line (login, lineno);
```

Assuming your columns are `NOT NULL`. Else, also consider:
[How to add a conditional unique index on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917065/how-to-add-a-conditional-unique-index-on-postgresql/8918141#8918141)