# How to ORDER BY an unaggregated column in subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, knn, hasura

I'm trying to create a function in Hasura that queries the posts near a user. I got that working but I would also like to order the posts. I get a Postgres error that says:

> "postgres-error : column "b.Volume" must appear in the GROUP BY clause
> or be used in an aggregate function"

I'm new to Hasura and Postgres and I'm not sure if you are allowed to do something like this or not.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.search_posts_near_user(id uuid, distance_kms integer, volume integer)
 RETURNS SETOF user_posts
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
  SELECT  A.id, A.location,
  (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(B)) FROM "Posts" B
   WHERE (
     ST_Distance(
       ST_Transform(B.location::Geometry, 3857),
       ST_Transform(A.location::Geometry, 3857)
     ) /1000) < distance_kms AND B."Volume" < volume
    ORDER BY B."Volume" Desc
   ) AS nearby_Posts
  FROM users A where A.id = id
$function$
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.search_posts_near_user(
      _id uuid
    , _distance_kms integer
    , _volume integer)
  RETURNS SETOF user_posts
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
SELECT  A.id, A.location
     , (SELECT json_agg(B.* ORDER BY B."Volume" DESC)
        FROM   "Posts" B
        WHERE  ST_Distance(ST_Transform(B.location::Geometry, 3857)
                         , ST_Transform(A.location::Geometry, 3857))
               < _distance_kms * 1000
        AND    B."Volume" < _volume
      ) AS nearby_Posts
FROM    users A
WHERE   A.id = _id
$func$;
```

Make sure that function parameters (and variables) do not collide with table column names. I prefixed with `_`. Not strictly necessary, but a good habit.

Note how I multiply `_distance_kms * 1000` instead of `ST_Distance() / 1000` like you had it. That's better for multiple reasons. Multiplication is cheaper to begin with, and it avoids rounding errors. And it is substantially cheaper to manipulate the constant value *once* than the computed values for every row. Finally, your original expression might prevent index support (if available), being non-["sargable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), which would be the strongest reason to fix it.

Basically, this is a KNN (k nearest neighbors) type of problem, that can benefit **a lot** from the right query technique in combination with the right index, typically a GiST index. See:

- [Unique assignment of closest points between two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517386/unique-assignment-of-closest-points-between-two-tables/34521492#34521492)

Also, while `ORDER BY` attached to the aggregate expression works conveniently, it is typically faster to sort in a subquery with `ORDER BY`, and then aggregate. See:

- [How to apply ORDER BY and LIMIT in combination with an aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213724/3684)

Aside:
My standing advice is to use legal, lower-case, unquoted names in Postgres exclusively. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)