# Constraint for nullable column involving column of another table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, constraints, unique-constraint

I have two tables:

```
table1:
id bigserial not null,
value1 integer not null

table2:
id bigserial not null,
table1_id bigint not null,(FK)
value2 character varying not null,
value3 character varying,
```

I need to add some constraint to be sure that when `value3` is not null, then combination of `value3`, `value2`, and `table1.value1` should be unique per `table2`. How can I do it?

Comment: Your Postgres version? And `table1.value1` is not defined UNIQUE?  (`table1.id` obviously requires a PK or UNIQUE constraint to allow the FK.) Write patterns? Is `table1` read-only?

Comment: table1.value1 is not unique. Table1.id is a PK. Postgres version 9.4

Comment: Please [edit] the question to present complete information. Comments are not the place.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you could have a partial UNIQUE index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table2_foo_idx ON table2 (value3, value2, table1_id)`
WHERE value3 IS NOT NULL;
```

Related:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)
- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values/9760#9760)

**But** this does not account for duplicate values of `value1` in `table1`. This cannot be enforced with a constraint without dirty tricks, since all relevant constraints only involve columns of the same table.

There are various **workarounds**, depending on the complete situation. Triggers, a partial functional unique multicolumn index using a fake immutable function, a (`NOT VALID`) `CHECK` constraint ...

One ***clean*** way to enforce this is to store `value1` in `table2` redundantly, add multicolumn FK constraint with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and create the unique index mentioned above:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   table1_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY
 , value1    text NOT NULL
 , UNIQUE   (value1, table1_id)  -- logically redundant, neede for FK
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
   table2_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY
 , table1_id bigint NOT NULL
 , value1    text NOT NULL
 , value2    text NOT NULL
 , value3    text
 , FOREIGN KEY (table1_id, value1) REFERENCES table1(table1_id, value1) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table2_foo_idx ON table2 (value3, value2, value1)`
WHERE value3 IS NOT NULL;
```

Related:

- [Enforcing constraints “two tables away”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)
- [Restrict foreign key relationship to rows of related subtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910861/restrict-foreign-key-relationship-to-rows-of-related-subtypes/24914798#24914798)

Chose an opportune order of columns in your unique index and constraint to best support typical queries without adding more indexes. Compare:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Comment: Value1 in table1 can be duplicate