# Storing unique values in the same table but with different parent values

Tags: database, postgresql, datatables

1. I have 2 tables **Parent** and **Child**.
2. **Child** has a unique attribute(*childNo*)
3. As long as 2 Children have different Parents, they should be able to have the same *childNo*.
4. 2 Children with the same Parents should not have the same *childNo*

I can't think of a way to implement this as I'm getting a unique constraint violation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [multicolumn `UNIQUE` index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) or [constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) on `child (childNo, parent_id)`.

This way, the same combination of `(childNo, parent_id)` cannot be entered a second time. That's all you need.
(Might also serve as `PRIMARY KEY`, replacing the additional `child.id`, but that depends ...)

If `child.parent_id` can be `NULL` (and you don't want two rows with the same `childNo` and `NULL`), consider:

- [How to add a conditional unique index on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917065/how-to-add-a-conditional-unique-index-on-postgresql/8918141#8918141)

And avoid CaMeL-case identifiers in Postgres to make your life easier. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Conceptually the OP wants a "constraint" so my guess it's better to present it as a contraint (when possible) rather than an index. Of course, both will work as expected.

Comment: @TheImpaler: Yeah, constraint should be the preferred route. Plus `NOT NULL` on both columns to rule out the mentioned corner case.

Comment: Thank you,Can this be implemented with sqlalchemy ORM in Flask? as it's what I'm using

Comment: @InternetPresence: I don't normally use ORMs, but I have no doubt it can.

Comment: I managed to make it work, used __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint("childNo","parent_id") in the Child class