# rows that violate unique constraints

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

I have a postgres 8.3.4 database. A name table exists with a unique constraint on the triplet UNIQ(name, id, age). Somehow there are several rows that have been added to the database that cause violation of this constraint.

My question is how is this possible ? Shouldn't the database have thrown an error when the first row that would violate the constraint was added ?

name : text
id : integer not null (fk to a id table)
age : integer

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.3 is no longer supported. If you cannot for some strange reason update to a current version (9.x) then you should at least update to the latest 8.3 version which is 8.3.18.

Comment: Are you sure the names are the same? Have you controlled for trailing white-space? And also, as many people have already commented, you would be wise to upgrade to a current version of PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 6):

#### Update

Postgres 15 added `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` for `UNIQUE` constraints and indexes. See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

#### Original answer

My **guess** is you are missing the fact that `NULL` values are considered to be distinct, i.e., do not conflict with a `UNIQUE` constraint. If you enter:

```
(NULL, 1, 20)
```

for `(name, id, age)` multiple times, you get no unique violation. Two `NULL` values are not considered "the same" (i.e. "distinct").

You can either set all involved columns **`NOT NULL`** (after replacing `NULL` values with dummy values).

Or you can implement [**additional partial indexes**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) to cover NULLs (after cleaning up "dupes" with `NULL`). For instance, if you need to cover the `name` column for NULLs:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_id_age_name_null_idx ON my_table (id, age)
WHERE name IS NULL;
```

Then you can have:

```
  ('pete', 1, 20)
, ('jane', 1, 20) 
, (NULL  , 1, 20)
```

for `(name, id, age)` in your table, but none of these a second time. See:

- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9760/3684)

Comment: all three columns are protected with a not-null constraint

Comment: @Finslicer: You might want to edit your question. The information there does not reflect what you are commenting here.

Answer (score 5):

It's hardly feasible.

Most probably, you have extra spaces in names or something like this.

Please post the exact table definition.

Also, please run this query:

```
SELECT  q2.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  name, id, age
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                name, id, age
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) q
JOIN    mytable q2
ON      (q2.name, q2.id, q2.age) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (q.name, q.id, q.age)
```

and post some output returned here.