# PostgreSQL Unique index compound key

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, indexing, unique-index

I need to create a restriction on a table based on four columns, and two of them are mutually exclusive, I mean, if one is NULL the other is not.

The ideal script would be this:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY t_users_prizes
ADD CONSTRAINT t_user_prize_test_circuit_key
UNIQUE (id_event||':'||id_circuit, id_prize, id_user);
```

But Postgres doesn't allow this kind of concatenation.

How can I implement this restriction?

Comment: Would you allow `(1, NULL, 3, 4)` and `(NULL, 1, 3, 4)` to coexist?

Comment: As I understand, contrary to the implied in both @Erwin and Catcall answers, that both the mutually exclusive columns can be not null. What is the correct interpretation?

Comment: Both our answers disallow a pair of NULLs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NULL` values do not violate a `UNIQUE` constraint - two `NULL` are not considered equal! So a simple `UNIQUE` constraint doesn't work.

You can get it done with **two [partial `UNIQUE` indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html)** and a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (
  a int
, b int
, c int NOT NULL
, d int NOT NULL
, CHECK ((a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NULL) OR (b IS NOT NULL AND a IS NULL))
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_acd_idx ON foo(a,c,d)
WHERE b is NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_bcd_idx ON foo(b,c,d)
WHERE a is NULL;

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL,2,3,4);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL,2,3,4);  -- error!
```

I declared `c` and `d` as `NOT NULL`, to prevent further complications.

See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

To also disallow `(1, NULL, 3, 4)` and `(NULL, 1, 3, 4)`, you could use one index with `COALESCE` instead:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_xcd_idx ON foo(COALESCE(a,b),c,d);
```

Comment: vey good answer! that solves the problem and encourages me to do new things in postgres. Thanks! (Next task: a partitioned table!)