# behavior of multi-column unique indexes with NULL values over multiple connections

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have a multi-column unique index in postgresql. Sometimes one of these column values will be NULL, and I'd like the unique index to treat NULL as just another value. So that these two rows are NOT allowed:

```
1,2,NULL
1,2,NULL
```

Doing simple experiments at psql, this is exactly the behavior I see.

But I have a stress test where I do 20 concurrent inserts using 20 threads. Here, Postgres allows the identical rows to be inserted.

Is there any reason for this to happen? Maybe there's another difference between my psql experiment and my test experiment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unique index will consider nulls to be different so those values can be inserted:

```
create table t (a int, b int, c int, unique (a, b, c));
insert into t (a, b, c) values
(1, 2, null),
(1, 2, null);
INSERT 0 2
```

Show your experiment in which that is not allowed.

Comment: gah, frak, it was my `ActiveRecord` validation that was stopping it. not sure how i missed this obvious thing in my test (especially since i thought i was explicitly testing them separately). okay thanks! i'll do the double index solution @dondimichaelstroma linked to