# Django unique together constraint failure?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Using Django 1.5.1. Python 2.7.3.

I wanted to do a unique together constraint with a foreign key field and a slug field. So in my model meta, I did

```
foreign_key = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, default=None)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=False)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ("foreign_key", "slug")
```

I even checked the table description in Postgres (9.1) and the constraint was put into the database table.

```
-- something like
"table_name_foreign_key_id_slug_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (foreign_key_id, slug)
```

However, I could still save into the database table a foreign_key of None/null and duplicate strings.

For example,

I could input and save

```
# model objects with slug="python" three times; all three foreign_key(s) 
# are None/null because that is their default value
MO(slug="python").save()
MO(slug="python").save()
MO(slug="python").save()
```

So after using unique_together, why can I still input three of the same valued rows?

I'm just guessing right now that it might have to do with the default value of None for the foreign_key field, because before the unique_together, when I just had unique=True on slug, everything worked fine. So if that is the case, what default value should I have that indicates a null value, but also maintains the unique constraint?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Postgresql `NULL` isn't equal to any other `NULL`. Therefore the rows you create are not the same (from Postgres' perspective).

**Update**

You have a few ways to deal with it:

- Forbid the `Null` value for foreign key and use some default value
- Override the `save` method of your model to check that no such row exists
- Change SQL standard :)

Comment: how do I correct this? Is there a value I can assign to the foreign key field or something like unique on slug if foreign key is NULL?

Comment: Is there a default value for a foreign key in postgres such that the value will never be naturally used?

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing. It will corrupt the schema. I would create a dummy object on the other side of the relation.

Comment: I think that `clean` method is more appropriate than `save` method for that task.

Comment: I like option 3 (Change SQL standard). This behavior is just painful.

Comment: From [the postrgres doc on `Unique Constraints`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS): `in the presence of a unique constraint it is possible to store duplicate rows that contain a null value in at least one of the constrained columns. This behavior conforms to the SQL standard, but we have heard that other SQL databases might not follow this rule. `

Comment: i think django should warn users about this by detecting the issue in the migration so that we can avoid these pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

Add a `clean` method to your model, so you can edit an existing row.

```
def clean(self):
    queryset = MO.objects.exclude(id=self.id).filter(slug=self.slug)
    if self.foreign_key is None:
        if queryset.exists():
            raise ValidationError("A row already exists with this slug and no key")
    else:
        if queryset.filter(foreign_key=self.foreign_key).exists():
            raise ValidationError("This row already exists")
```

Beware, `clean` (or `full_clean`) isn't called by the default `save` method.

NB: if you put this code in the `save` method, update forms (like in the admin) won't work: you will have a traceback error due to the `ValidationError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just manually create secondary index on `slug` field, but only for NULL values in `foreign_key_id`:

```
CREATE INDEX table_name_unique_null_foreign_key
  ON table_name (slug) WHERE foreign_key_id is NULL
```

Please note, that Django does not support this, so without custom form/model validation you will get pure IntegrityError / 500.

Possible duplicate of [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns)

Answer (score 0):

As hobbyte mentioned, "In Postgresql NULL isn't equal to any other NULL. Therefore the rows you create are not the same (from Postgres' perspective)."

Another possible way to address this challenge is to add custom validation at the view level in the form_valid method.

In views.py:

```html
def form_valid(self, form): 

  --OTHER VALIDATION AND FIELD VALUE ASSIGNMENT LOGIC--

  if ModelForm.objects.filter(slug=slug,foreign_key=foreign_key:   
    form.add_error('field',
      forms.ValidationError( _("Validation error message that shows up in your form. "), 
      code='duplicate_row', )) 
    return self.form_invalid(form)
```

This approach is helpful if you are using class based views, especially if you are automatically assigning values to fields that you want to hide from the user.

Pros:

- You don't have to create dummy default values in the database
- You can still use update forms (see Toff's answer)

Cons:
 - This doesn't protect against duplicate rows created directly at the database level.
 - If you use Django's admin backend to create new MyModel objects, you'll need to add this same validation logic to your admin form.