# Django unique_together with nullable ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I'm using Django 1.8.4 in my dev machine using Sqlite and I have these models:

```
class ModelA(Model):
    field_a = CharField(verbose_name='a', max_length=20)
    field_b = CharField(verbose_name='b', max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('field_a', 'field_b',)


class ModelB(Model):
    field_c = CharField(verbose_name='c', max_length=20)
    field_d = ForeignKey(ModelA, verbose_name='d', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('field_c', 'field_d',)
```

I've run proper migration and registered them in the Django Admin. So, using the Admin I've done this tests:

- I'm able to create ModelA records and Django prohibits me from creating duplicate records - as expected!
- I'm not able to create identical ModelB records when field_b is not empty
- But, I'm able to create identical ModelB records, when using field_d as empty

My question is: How do I apply unique_together for nullable ForeignKey?

The most recent answer I found for this problem has 5 year... I do think Django have evolved and the issue may not be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django unique together constraint failure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510261/django-unique-together-constraint-failure)

Comment: @Ivan I've tried this post too, but it did not helped me with the modelformset. When trying to create identical records in the same formset, Django doesn't prohibit. The user is still able to create duplicate items

Comment: "I'm not able to create identical ModelB records when field_b is not empty"
Did you mean "field_d"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE**: previous version of my answer was functional but had bad design, this one takes in account some of the comments and other answers.

In SQL NULL does not equal NULL. This means if you have two objects where `field_d == None and field_c == "somestring"` they are not equal, so you can create both.

You can override `Model.clean` to add your check:

```
class ModelB(Model):
    #...
    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        if ModelB.objects.exclude(id=self.id).filter(field_c=self.field_c, \
                                 field_d__isnull=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Duplicate ModelB")
        super(ModelB, self).validate_unique(exclude)
```

If used outside of forms you have to call `full_clean` or `validate_unique`.

Take care to handle the race condition though.

Comment: Tx @Ivan, but should I be able to creat two ModelB records with `field_c=="a", field_d==None` ??

Comment: And how can I change this behaviour :)

Comment: tx! It is still not solved for me. I'm using a formset and just by overriding clean method, when the user fills two forms both are valid (formset.is_valid()) but when the first is saved the second one becomes invalid. You get my point? Any tip regarding formsets and this post?

Comment: I think `validate_unique` would be a better method to override than `clean`...no?

Comment: It works for me but I had to check that the instance I was running validation on had its nullable field set to null. Which looks missing here.

Answer (score 84):

Django 2.2 added a new [constraints API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) which makes addressing this case much easier within the database.

You will need two constraints:

1. The existing tuple constraint; and
2. The remaining keys minus the nullable key, with a condition

If you have multiple nullable fields, I guess you will need to handle the permutations.

Here's an example with a thruple of fields that must be all unique, where only one `NULL` is permitted:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.constraints import UniqueConstraint

class Badger(models.Model):
    required = models.ForeignKey(Required, ...)
    optional = models.ForeignKey(Optional, null=True, ...)
    key = models.CharField(db_index=True, ...)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['required', 'optional', 'key'],
                             name='unique_with_optional'),
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['required', 'key'],
                             condition=Q(optional=None),
                             name='unique_without_optional'),
        ]
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest way to handle such scenarios.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer.

Comment: Great answer. Too bad MySQL does not support it :(

Comment: Great answer, but in my case in the same migration should have been created a referenced field, and this step was placed after creation of constraints, it caused exception `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist`. I had to manually reorder steps in migration and it worked for me.

Comment: For those interested, this is the best answer I found re: raw SQL https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9760/212269

Comment: Also, as stated in the [djanog-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) `unique_together` may eventually be deprecated in favor of `UniqueConstraints`. So `UniqueConstraints` seems like the preferred solution, in general.

Comment: Not sure about MySQL , but in MariaDB 10.x , a composite unique constraint ([unique index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-indexes/#unique-index))  can be NULL if one of the columns is NULL. The code in this answer can work in MariaDB for composite unique constraint  with many foreign keys.

Answer (score 11):

@ivan, I don't think that there's a simple way for django to manage this situation. You need to think of all creation and update operations that don't always come from a form.  Also, you should think of race conditions...

And because you don't force this logic on DB level, it's possible that there actually will be doubled records and you should check it while querying results.

And about your solution, it can be good for form, but I don't expect that save method can raise ValidationError.

If it's possible then it's better to delegate this logic to DB. In this particular case, you can use two partial indexes. There's a similar question on StackOverflow - [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns)

So you can create Django migration, that adds two partial indexes to your DB

Example:

```
# Assume that app name is just `example`

CREATE_TWO_PARTIAL_INDEX = """
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX model_b_2col_uni_idx ON example_model_b (field_c, field_d)
    WHERE field_d IS NOT NULL;

    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX model_b_1col_uni_idx ON example_model_b (field_c)
    WHERE field_d IS NULL;
"""

DROP_TWO_PARTIAL_INDEX = """
    DROP INDEX model_b_2col_uni_idx;
    DROP INDEX model_b_1col_uni_idx;
"""


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('example', 'PREVIOUS MIGRATION NAME'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(CREATE_TWO_PARTIAL_INDEX, DROP_TWO_PARTIAL_INDEX)
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, and in my other answers I usually add that it will only work if `clean` is called. On the other hand I generally try to avoid having sneaky db modifications outside the model code, except for data migrations.

Comment: +1 Data integrity constraints should live as close to the data as possible, and the best way to do that is with a DB constraint. Any python approach (like the accepted answer) will have race condition issues.

Comment: Can this be done with Mysql? My understanding is that there is no feature like  "Where is NULL"  when creating unique constraints with Mysql

Comment: @PatrickKenekayoro, no, MySQL has no such thing as a partial index. Look into that for more info https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106593 Only reasonable solution is to make this functionality as a part of your code base, like suggested Ivan

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround not mentioned yet is to create a dummy `ModelA` object to serve as your `NULL` value. Then you can rely on the database to enforce the uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Add a clean method to your model - *see below*:

```
def clean(self):
        if Variants.objects.filter("""Your filter """).exclude(pk=self.pk).exists():
            raise ValidationError("This variation is duplicated.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Django 5.0, you can easily achieve this through the [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) class with the use of `nulls_distinct`.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.constraints import UniqueConstraint

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    required = models.ForeignKey(...)
    optional = models.ForeignKey(..., null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['required', 'optional'],
                nulls_distinct=False
            )
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more clear way to do that for Django 1.2+

In forms it will be raised as non_field_error with no 500 error, in other cases, like DRF you have to check this case manual, because it will be 500 error.
But it will always check for unique_together!

```
class BaseModelExt(models.Model):
is_cleaned = False

def clean(self):
    for field_tuple in self._meta.unique_together[:]:
        unique_filter = {}
        unique_fields = []
        null_found = False
        for field_name in field_tuple:
            field_value = getattr(self, field_name)
            if getattr(self, field_name) is None:
                unique_filter['%s__isnull' % field_name] = True
                null_found = True
            else:
                unique_filter['%s' % field_name] = field_value
                unique_fields.append(field_name)
        if null_found:
            unique_queryset = self.__class__.objects.filter(**unique_filter)
            if self.pk:
                unique_queryset = unique_queryset.exclude(pk=self.pk)
            if unique_queryset.exists():
                msg = self.unique_error_message(self.__class__, tuple(unique_fields))

                raise ValidationError(msg)

    self.is_cleaned = True

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.is_cleaned:
        self.clean()

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```