# How to create a unique-together constraint in Django that ignores NULL?

Tags: sql, django

How does Django deal with NULL with its unique index? Is there a way to allow for many NULL rows, while enforcing uniqueness on non-null values?

And then, the same question for unique_together. Is there a way to enforce unique_together, but if any of the fields are NULL, allow for that row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django unique\_together with nullable ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307892/django-unique-together-with-nullable-foreignkey)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about MySQL, but SQLite and PostgreSQL do not consider `NULL` values to be equal, so the behavior you are looking for is actually the default.

You can verify this yourself:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, null=True, max_length=255)

>>> MyModel.objects.create()
<MyModel: MyModel object (1)>
>>> MyModel.objects.create()
<MyModel: MyModel object (2)>
```

For a `unique_together`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('title', 'description'),)

>>> MyModel.objects.create(title='x')
<MyModel: MyModel object (1)>
>>> MyModel.objects.create(title='x')
<MyModel: MyModel object (2)>
```

Note that in the second example, there is no unique constraint on the `title` field, only the unique together on both fields.