# How to enforce uniqueness with NULL values in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a model with a non-nullable `CharField` and 2 x nullable `CharField`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, null=False)
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=255, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField('Position', max_length=255, blank=True)
```

I want to ensure that `name`, `title`, and `position` are unique together, and so use a `UniqueConstraint`:

```
def Meta:
    constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['name', 'title', 'position'],
                name="unique_name_title_position"
            ),
        ]
```

However, if `title` is `None` then this constraint fails.

Looking into why, this is because you can insert `NULL` values into columns with the `UNIQUE` constraint because `NULL` is the absence of a value, so it is never equal to other `NULL` values and not considered a duplicate value. This means that it's possible to insert rows that appear to be duplicates if one of the values is `NULL`.

What's the correct way to strictly enforce this uniqueness in Django?

Comment: Make the nullable columns also non-nullable? What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: what database are you using

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58830230/6602608

Comment: @iklinac PostgreSQL 12

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko That would not meet my use case. E.g. if `title` and `position` is NULL I want only one `name`. If only `position` is NULL I want one `name` and `title`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `add one more constraint` when `title` is `NULL`

```
models.UniqueConstraint(
    name='only_one_null',
    fields=('name', 'position'),
                condition=Q(title__isnull=True)
)
```

This should guarantee uniqueness with NULL values in `title`. You can add more constraints as you wish for `NULL` values

Answer (score 0):

[`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) are not enforced on Django level but rather directly on database.

PostgreSQL for instance allows multiple `Null` records for unique while MSSQL does not

You can rather check if for each subset of columns with [`CheckConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) but as you will find out this is tedious as it requires each combination to be uniquely [indexed](http://%20https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values).

---

Rather to avoid even whole this mess you can follow Django guide for `CharField`
as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null)

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
> TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has
> two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most
> cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the
> Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. One exception
> is when a CharField has both unique=True and blank=True set. In this
> situation, null=True is required to avoid unique constraint violations
> when saving multiple objects with blank values.

Empty string is checked for uniqueness

Answer (score -1):

You could pick values that don't ever occur for `title` and `position` and use an index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON mytable (
   name,
   coalesce(title, '#impossible#'),
   coalesce(position, '#impossible#'),
);
```

That will replace the NULL values with something else, so that duplicates are prevented.