# Django allowing duplicate records despite having unique_together constraints

Tags: django

My django model has three fields,
company_id
jurisdiction
businessStartDate

I have added below constraints,

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'payroll'
    unique_together = (
        'Company_id',
        'jurisdiction',
        'businessStartDate',
    )
```

Despite adding these constraints and using get_or_create to add new records, I am seeing duplicate records being inserted in the table.

```
z, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
       Company_id=Company_id, jurisdiction=jurisdiction, businessStartDate__isnull=True
)
```

Here is the snapshot of mysql table,

```
mysql> select Company_id, jurisdiction, businessStartDate from companyjurisdiction;
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
|   Company_id | jurisdiction | businessStartDate |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
|       496395 | CA           | NULL              |
|       496395 | CA           | NULL              |
|       496395 | FED          | NULL              |
|       496395 | MI           | NULL              |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here? Does having NULL values in businessStartDate column creating this issue?

Comment: Can you share the get_or_create part of code?

Comment: @JLeno46 I added it above.

Comment: Some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307892/django-unique-together-with-nullable-foreignkey) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510291/11426745) you're looking for. MySQL and Postgres treat NULL likewise.