# duplicate null value violation on UNIQUE KEY constraint in Mssql

Tags: sql-server, database, null, unique-constraint

MS SQL Server does not ignore the null value and considers it as violation for the UNIQUE KEY constraint but what I know is that the UNIQUE KEY  differ from the primary key where it accepts the null value.

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'AK_UserName'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.users'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Create a filtered unique index, where column is not null. That way the index does not include the null values.

Comment: but it accept only one `NULL` value not multiple , check your table i think one `NULL` already exist

Comment: @tinka, yes I have one `null` in my table but it must accept more than one `null`.

Comment: @user3260672 no Not http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80514/why-does-a-unique-constraint-allow-only-one-null

Comment: See [Is it possible for unique column to contain multiple null values SQL Server 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81293)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can create a unique index that ignores null values like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_col1
ON dbo.MyTable(col1)
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Very useful - strange that it's not included in the examples of the `WHERE` clause in the [CREATE INDEX documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188783.aspx)

Comment: note that WITH ( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
    ON [PRIMARY]  must be placed after the where of course

Comment: That is very helpful, I was looking for this. Thank you @GuidoG

Comment: Entity Framework Migration, use like: 
Sql("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_PaymentId] ON [dbo].[Order]([PaymentId]) WHERE [PaymentId] IS NOT NULL;");

Comment: Important to note that your column must not have a UNIQUE constraint in its defintion and this should be handled via the Index.