# SQLAlchemy and mssql : how to create unique constraint with multiple null value

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, null, unique-constraint

I am working with SQLAlchemy and MS SQL server and I would like to create a unique constraint that allows multiple NULL value.

I know that MS SQL server  does not ignore the null value and considers it as violation for the UNIQUE KEY.
I also know how to fix it with SQL code (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947263/duplicate-null-value-violation-on-unique-key-constraint-in-mssql/31949874))

But is there a way to do the same thing with SQLAlchemy directly ?

Here is my code :

```
class Referential(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = "REFERENTIAL"
     id = db.Column("ID", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
     name = db.Column("NAME", String(100), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
     internal_code = db.Column("INTERNAL_CODE", String(50), unique=True, index=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL's implementation when it comes to allowing nulls in a unique column is a little odd.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

sa.Table(
    sa.Column('column', sa.String(50), nullable=True),
    sa.Index('uq_column_allows_nulls', mssql_where=sa.text('column IS NOT NULL'),
)
```

If you are planning on using alembic like I was this is the code:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import alembic as op

op.create_index(
    name='uq_column_name',
    table_name='table',
    columns=['column'],
    mssql_where=sa.text('column IS NOT NULL'),
)
```

This uses the [sql expression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) text for sqlalchemy and `create_index`'s [dialect_expression key word arguments](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html?highlight=unique#alembic.operations.Operations.create_index) `mssql_where=`