# MSSQL: Add Unique Constraint at Create Table and allow NULLs

Tags: sql-server

Sorry, probably noob question, but I couldn't find an answer.

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
   Id DECIMAL NOT NULL,
   UserIdentifier NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Id),
   ????
)
```

How to add a unique key constraint within the CREATE TABLE on column UserIdentifier which allows Nulls?

I know outside CREATE TABLE you could say ... WHERE UserIdentifier IS NOT NULL, but within?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I only now see you're asking for the inline syntax for a filtered unique index, embedding the index within the `CREATE TABLE`. That's easy: there isn't one. Unfortunately, T-SQL is not fully consistent in this manner. This typically doesn't matter much unless you absolutely, positively have to have a single statement for some reason.  Note also that unique *constraints* (not indexes) do not allow filtering; this is only possible for unique indexes.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947263/duplicate-null-value-violation-on-unique-key-constraint-in-mssql/31949874#31949874) can help you. You can create unique index that allows null for multiple records

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Assuming* that you want multiple rows with the value `NULL`, you won't be able to use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, as `NULL` is still a value (even if an unknown one). For example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier nvarchar(100) NULL,
                            CONSTRAINT UC_UI UNIQUE (UserIdentifier));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier)
VALUES(NULL);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier)
VALUES(NULL);
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Notice the second `INSERT` fails.

You can, instead, however, use a conditional `UNIQUE INDEX`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier nvarchar(100) NULL);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UI_UI ON dbo.YourTable(UserIdentifier) WHERE UserIdentifier IS NOT NULL;

GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier)
VALUES(NULL); -- Success
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier)
VALUES(NULL); --Success
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier)
VALUES(N'Steve'); --Success
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier)
VALUES(N'Jayne'); --Success
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier)
VALUES(N'Steve'); --Fails
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

<strike>As Jeroen Mostert stated in the comments though, you cannot create a unique index as part of creating the table; it must be created in a separate statement. There is no syntax to create an `UNIQUE INDEX` as part of a `CREATE TABLE` statement.</strike>

You can create this inline (it was [undocumented](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/3648) at the time of this answer was originally written) with either of the following syntax in SQL Server 2016+:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (UserIdentifier nvarchar(100) NULL INDEX UI_UI UNIQUE WHERE UserIdentifier IS NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (UserIdentifier nvarchar(100) NULL,
                            INDEX UI_UI UNIQUE (UserIdentifier)  WHERE UserIdentifier IS NOT NULL);
```

[db<>fiddle 2014](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4c2c3bdca3f6ed7826e0ae4c0b843381), [db<>fiddle 2016](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4c2c3bdca3f6ed7826e0ae4c0b843381)

Comment: FYI, @Powerslave, this has been updated, as you *can* do this inline (at the time I'm not sure it was documented) and this is newer syntax; looks like it was added in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple. If you want to add on single column then apply on column level by just adding `UNIQUE` keyword.
But if you want this to be on basis of multiple column then need to add `CONSTRAINT`. For more info you may find this link .[link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,   --- FOR ADDING ON ONE COLUMN
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (ID,LastName)   --- FOR MULTIPLE COLUMNS
);
```

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP's question was about applying a `UNIQUE` constraint on a column that allowed NULLs (in the actual Table Creation definition).

There appears to be an option for adding it afterwards: 
`CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UniqueExceptNulls]
ON [SomeTable] (UserIdentifier)
WHERE [UserIdentifier] IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server using `UNIQUE` keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
   Id DECIMAL NOT NULL,
   UserIdentifier NVARCHAR(100) NULL UNIQUE,
   PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

and when trying to insert same value again in the column, it will throw error.

Please find the same execution in the demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=12f68484beebb1bf957a8259777465c9)

Comment: That won't allow `NULL`s though. Well, it will allow a single `NULL`, after which it will throw a constraint violation error.