# Visual Studio 2019 - SQL dacpac - Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint ....The duplicate key value is (<NULL>)

Tags: sql, null, constraints, unique

I use a database project in visual studio

I tried to get rid of that error by allowing UNIQUE NULLABLES but it keeps appearing

**I want fields to have unique values EXCEPT when they are null**

(I know there are many answers but they dont relate to a create table query)

what do I do wrong ?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users] ( 
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Email]          VARCHAR (100) UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    [Login]          VARCHAR (100) UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    [Identifier] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT newid(),
    [ResetPasswordToken] VARCHAR(40) UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED NULL DEFAULT   NULL,
    [ResetPasswordDate]DATETIME UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED NULL DEFAULT   NULL,
...(other fields)
);
```

thanks for your help on this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [duplicate null value violation on UNIQUE KEY constraint in Mssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947263/duplicate-null-value-violation-on-unique-key-constraint-in-mssql)

Comment: no, it's the first answer I read, as I mentioned it is not a create table and my above code is not working

Comment: Why do you try to achieve it in `create table`? The approach in that answer do the same, but outside of table definition (I mean unique is constraint enforced by unique index no matter where it was declared).

Answer (score 0):

the answer is about using the word "GO"

```
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User_Email] ON [dbo].[Users]([Email] ASC) WHERE ([Email] IS NOT NULL);

GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User_Login] ON [dbo].[Users]([Login] ASC) WHERE ([Login] IS NOT NULL);

GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User_ResetPasswordToken] ON [dbo].[Users]([ResetPasswordToken] ASC) WHERE ([ResetPasswordToken] IS NOT NULL);

GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User_ResetPasswordDate] ON [dbo].[Users]([ResetPasswordDate] ASC) WHERE ([ResetPasswordDate] IS NOT NULL);
```