# Nulls in one of the columns in a composite unique index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a unique index on (id, name) columns. I have a date column that I want to add to the index since I want the uniqueness to be based on (id, name, date) columns. The date column contains a lot of null values. How would it affect the index?

Comment: `NULL` would be treated as a value. So you couldn't have more than 1 row with the same value of `id` and `name` where the value of `date` was `NULL`. If you want `NULL` values to be ignored, you'd need to use a "filtered" unique index.

Comment: Larnu has just written exactly what I was about to say, almost word for word, so I won't repeat it, but here's a fiddle that demonstrates it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d5362bd3e746656faa71b8c9345636c

Comment: You can create an unique index that ignores null values, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947263/duplicate-null-value-violation-on-unique-key-constraint-in-mssql/31949874#31949874). But in this case (more than one column in your index) it does means your combined uniqueness is not what you expect. The example of GarethD shows that perfect

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Very valuable information. Would changing the current index affect the performance of the index?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, so in SQL Server null values are not included in the index structure, But SQL Server has some new features, one of the `filtering index`. If a field has many null values so recommended creating an additional filtering index using where the field is null condition.

[For more information about filtering index visit this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-design/filtered-index-with-column-is-null)

**Final result:** You can do your add index operations comfortably, without problems, in many Databases null values don't affect performance.