# SQL unique constraint of a max of two entries per user

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-trigger, unique-constraint

Is it possible to generate a unique constraint in SQL that will allow a single user (`user_id`) up to two entries that are enabled (`enabled`)? An example is as follows

```
user_id  | enabled
------------------
123      | true
123      | true
123      | false
456      | true
```

The above would be valid, but adding another `user_id = 123` and `enabled = true` would fail because there would be three entries. Additionally adding `user_id = 123` and `enabled = false` would be valid because the table would still satisfy the rule.

Comment: No, a unique constraint cannot allow duplicates.  You probably need a trigger for this.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a constraint concerning a max number of rows in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743439/how-to-write-a-constraint-concerning-a-max-number-of-rows-in-postgresql)

Comment: Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot allow two values of "enabled".  But here is a solution that comes close to what you want without using triggers.  The idea is to encode the value as numbers and enforce uniqueness on two of the values:

```
create table t (
    user_id int,
    enabled_code int,
    is_enabled boolean as (enabled_code <> 0),
    check (enabled_code in (0, 1, 2))
);

create unique index unq_t_enabled_code_1
    on t(user_id, enabled_code)
    where enabled_code = 1;

create unique index unq_t_enabled_code_2
    on t(user_id, enabled_code)
    where enabled_code = 2;
```

Inserting new values is a bit tricky, because you need to check if the value goes in slot "1" or "2".  However, you can use `is_enabled` as the boolean value for querying.

Answer (score 3):

You could make it work by adding another `boolean` column to the `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint (or `UNIQUE` index):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   user_id int
 , enabled bool
 , enabled_first bool DEFAULT true
 , PRIMARY KEY (user_id, enabled, enabled_first)
);
```

`enabled_first` tags the first of each instance with `true`. I made it `DEFAULT true` to allow simple insert for the first `enabled` per `user_id` - without mentioning the added `enabled_first`. An explicit  `enabled_first = false` is required to insert a second instance.

**`NULL` values** are excluded automatically by the PK constraint I used. Be aware that a simple `UNIQUE` constraint still allows `NULL` values, working around your desired constraint. You would have to define all three columns `NOT NULL` additionally. See:

- [Allow null in unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154033/allow-null-in-unique-column/20154518#20154518)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a21710610885aba4bd9aaafd6e69e0c5)*

Of course, now the two `true` / `false` values are different internally, and you need to adjust write operations. This may or may not be acceptable. May even be desirable.

Welcome side-effect: Since the minimum payload (actual data size) is 8 bytes per index tuple, and boolean occupies 1 byte without requiring alignment padding, the index is still the same minimum size as for just `(user_id, enabled)`.
Similar for the table: the added `boolean` does not increase physical storage. (May not apply for tables with more columns.) See:

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Answer (score 1):

It has been explained already that a constraint or unique index only cannot enforce the logic that you want.

An alternative approach would be to use a materialized view. The logic is to use window functions to create an additional column in the view that resets every two rows having the same `(user_id, enabled)`. You can then put a unique partial index on that column. Finally, you can create a trigger that refreshes the view everytime a record is inserted or updated, which effectively enforces the unique constraint.

```
-- table set-up
create table mytable(user_id int, enabled boolean);

-- materialized view set-up
create materialized view myview as 
select 
    user_id, 
    enabled, 
    (row_number() over(partition by user_id, enabled) - 1) % 2 rn 
from mytable;

-- unique partial index that enforces integrity
create unique index on myview(user_id, rn) where(enabled);

-- trigger code
create or replace function refresh_myview()
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    refresh materialized view myview;
    return null;
end$$;

create trigger refresh_myview
after insert or update
on mytable for each row
execute procedure refresh_myview();
```

With this set-up in place, let's insert the initial content:

```
insert into mytable values
    (123, true),
    (123, true),
    (234, false),
    (234, true);
```

This works, and the content of the view is now:

```
user_id | enabled | rn
------: | :------ | -:
    123 | t       |  0
    123 | t       |  1
    234 | f       |  0
    234 | t       |  0
```

Now if we try to insert a row that violates the constraint, an error is raised, and the `insert` is rejected.

```
insert into mytable values(123, true);
-- ERROR:  could not create unique index "myview_user_id_rn_idx"
-- DETAIL:  Key (user_id, rn)=(123, 0) is duplicated.
-- CONTEXT:  SQL statement "refresh materialized view myview"
-- PL/pgSQL function refresh_myview() line 3 at SQL statement
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f08aebee1619603ca4ece2e7d4617bbe)**