# Why does distinct on in subqueries hurt performance in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, performance, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance, distinct-on

I've got a table `users` with fields `id` and `email`. `id` is the primary key and `email` is indexed as well.

```
database> \d users
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Column                      | Type                        | Modifiers                                           |
|-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------|
| id                          | integer                     |  not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass) |
| email                       | character varying           |                                                     |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_users_on_email" UNIQUE, btree (email)
```

If I query the table with a `distinct on (email)` clause in a subquery I get a significant performance penalty.

```sql
database> explain (analyze, buffers)
   select
     id
   from (
     select distinct on (email)
       id
     from
       users
   ) as t
   where id = 123
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Subquery Scan on t  (cost=8898.69..10077.84 rows=337 width=4) (actual time=221.133..250.782 rows=1 loops=1)                 |
|   Filter: (t.id = 123)                                                                                                      |
|   Rows Removed by Filter: 67379                                                                                             |
|   Buffers: shared hit=2824, temp read=288 written=289                                                                       |
|   ->  Unique  (cost=8898.69..9235.59 rows=67380 width=24) (actual time=221.121..247.582 rows=67380 loops=1)                 |
|         Buffers: shared hit=2824, temp read=288 written=289                                                                 |
|         ->  Sort  (cost=8898.69..9067.14 rows=67380 width=24) (actual time=221.120..239.573 rows=67380 loops=1)             |
|               Sort Key: users.email                                                                                         |
|               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2304kB                                                                     |
|               Buffers: shared hit=2824, temp read=288 written=289                                                           |
|               ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..3494.80 rows=67380 width=24) (actual time=0.009..9.714 rows=67380 loops=1) |
|                     Buffers: shared hit=2821                                                                                |
| Planning Time: 0.243 ms                                                                                                     |
| Execution Time: 251.258 ms                                                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Compare this with `distinct on (id)` whose cost is less than one thousandth of the previous query.

```
database> explain (analyze, buffers)
   select
     id
   from (
     select distinct on (id)
       id
     from
       users
   ) as t
   where id = 123
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Unique  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)                                          |
|   Buffers: shared hit=3                                                                                                     |
|   ->  Index Only Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=1) |
|         Index Cond: (id = 123)                                                                                              |
|         Heap Fetches: 1                                                                                                     |
|         Buffers: shared hit=3                                                                                               |
| Planning Time: 0.090 ms                                                                                                     |
| Execution Time: 0.034 ms                                                                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why is this?

The real problem I'm having is that I'm trying to create a view that does `distinct on` an indexed column that isn't unique and the performance is very bad.

Comment: You're forcing the server to do a bogus `distinct` since you're going to discard the results. In the last case the server was able to detect this since only the unique `id` column is involved and simply discard that `DISTINCT` operation. In the previous case it *had* to calculate `distinct on` to find which `ID` values are returned before it can filter them

Comment: The two queries return different results. The first one may return *no* results if there is an `id` less than `123` for an email. In the second case there's always a result as a `DISTINCT` on a `UNIQUE` index just returns the indexed values

Comment: I've updated the question using `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Logical difference

Both columns `id` and `email` are `UNIQUE`. But only `id` is **`NOT NULL`**. (`PRIMARY KEY` columns always are.) `NULL` values are not considered equal, multiple `NULL` values are allowed in a column with `UNIQUE` constraint (or index). That's according to standard SQL. See:

- [Allow null in unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154033/allow-null-in-unique-column/20154518#20154518)

But `DISTINCT` or `DISTINCT ON` consider NULL values  equal. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT)

> Obviously, two rows are considered distinct if they differ in at least
> one column value. **Null values are considered equal in this comparison.**

Bold emphasis mine. Further reading:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

In your second query, `distinct on (id)` is a logical no-op: the result is guaranteed to be the same as without `DISTINCT ON`. And since the outer `SELECT` filters on `id = 123`, Postgres can strip the noise and work off a very cheap index-only scan.

In your first query, on the other hand, `distinct on (email)` might actually do something if there are more than one rows with `email IS NULL`. Then Postgres has to pick the first `id` according to the given sort order. Since there is no `ORDER BY`, it results in an arbitrary pick. But the outer `SELECT` with the predicate `where id = 123` may depend on the result. The whole query is different from the first on principle - and broken by design.

#### Serendipity

All that aside, two "lucky" findings stick out:

> ```
> Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2304kB
> ```

Mention of "Disk" indicates insufficient [work_mem](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM). See:

- [Configuration parameter work_mem in PostgreSQL on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106181/configuration-parameter-work-mem-in-postgresql-on-linux/8108807#8108807)

> ```
>           ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..3494.80 rows=67380
> ```

In my tests, I always got an index scan here. Indicates a bloated index or some other problem with your setup.

#### Useful comparison?

The comparison is going nowhere. We might learn something from
comparing the first query with this query - after switching roles of PK and UNIQUE column:

```sql
select email
from  (select distinct on (id) email from users) t
where email = 'user123@foo.com';
```

Or from comparing the second query with this one - trying the same with the UNIQUE column instead of the PK column:

```sql
select email
from  (select distinct on (email) email from users) t
where email = 'user123@foo.com';
```

We learn that PK and UNIQUE constraint show no different effect on query plans. Postgres does not use the meta-information to cut corners. The PK would actually make a difference with `GROUP BY`. See:

- [Unexpected behaviour for GROUP BY query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/272988/3684)

So this works:

```sql
SELECT email
FROM  (
   SELECT email -- no aggregate required, because id = PK
   FROM   users
   GROUP  BY id  -- !
   ) t
WHERE email = 'user123@foo.com';
```

But the same does not work after switching `id` and `email`. I added some demos to the fiddle:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d9dbe0c8c82a2ac1573b191f7ff48c8f)*

#### So?

**Both queries are nonsense** for different reasons. I don't see how they can help with your real query:

> The real problem I'm having is that I'm trying to create a view that does distinct on an indexed column that **isn't unique** and the performance is very bad.

We'd need to see your real query - and all other relevant details of your setup. There may be solutions, but that may well beyond the scope of a question on SO. Consider hiring a consultant. Or consider one of these methods to optimize performance:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)