# In SQL, can I add a unique constraint to a field that's not required?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a standard User entity, with a name, mobile phone number, and email address. Of course, I don't want any duplication in the email address, but I also don't want it to be required. I'm not sure if a unique constraint lets multiple records be blank. (Wouldn't that violate uniqueness?) Is this even possible? If so, how do I specify this constraint in JPA?

Comment: This depends on the database.  Some databases allow duplicates with `NULL` values; some only allow one `NULL` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - yes, this is possible. Uniqueness means the column can't have two equal values. `null`s in SQL are not values - they are the lack thereof. Since they are not values, they don't affect the uniqueness, and a unique column can have as many `null`s as you like.

In JPA, you can specify this with the `unique` attribute of the `@Column` annotation:

```
@Column(unique=true)
String email;
```

Comment: `Since they are not values, they don't affect the uniqueness, and a unique column can have as many nulls as you like` => [Counterexample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bd76d0895e38e02027202d05693dec8). It depends on RDBMS, but could be easily resolved with filtered unique index

Answer (score 0):

Unique constraint won’t allow multiple null valujes but there is a solution for that - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/allow-nulls-unique-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Using a unique constraint on the email column will do what you want.  This has been answered previously here - [Allow null in unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154033/allow-null-in-unique-column).

```
@Column(unique=true)
String email;
```