# MySQL: Creating a Constraint with WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have a MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `users votes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `forumtopicid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `replyid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

I'm trying to create two unique constraints:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_first
ON `users votes`(userid, forumtopicid, replyid)
WHERE forumtopicid IS NOT NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_second 
ON `users votes`(userid, replyid) 
WHERE forumtopicid IS NULL;
```

This is throwing an error that I'm unsure how to fix. Is it not possible to add a WHERE clause for MySQL constraints?

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE forumtopicid IS NOT NULL' at line 3
```

Comment: Since you have `NOT NULL` in the table schema, why do you need this constraint in the index? The field can never be null.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct - you cannot use `WHERE` in `CREATE INDEX` statements (in mysql).

Comment: Seems I misunderstood, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/618584 works for postgresql but there is no MySQl alternative. :(