# ORM UniqueConstraint, null value duplicate

Tags: symfony, orm, unique-constraint

I have an entity with an unique constraint on 3 fiels.

2 fields are not nullable, and the third is nullable.

My problem, when the third field is null, the unique constraint doesn't work, so i can have in my database some duplicate values like (`5,1,null)(5,1,null)`

For me, (`5,1,null)` is an unique value, with null too.

Do you have any ideas ?

This is my ORM line :

```
* @ORM\Table(name="table", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="table_idx", columns={"field1", "field2", "field3"})})
```

Edit : The nullable value is a foreign key to an other entity, so i can't put a custom value. It's an entity or null.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but quoting the docs `a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: I don't want permits multiple null value. For me null is a real value.

Comment: That is because NULL is an unknown value and the result of comparing two unknown values is also unknown. Maybe you could use a special value instead of NULL?

Comment: Then you will have to use some sort of special flag.

Comment: i can't, the third value is a foreign key to an other entity. so it is an entity or null

Answer (score 6):

This could be achieved using [two partial indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253). But doctrine annotations is not enough. We should add some SQL to solve the issue.

**NOTE! I'm using PostgreSQL and [migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) in my project.**

First create 2 unique indexes (I use `YAML`):

```
uniqueConstraints:
    table_idx_2_fields:
        columns: [ field1, field2 ]
    table_idx_3_fields:
        columns: [ field1, field2, field3 ]
```

Then generate migration class using console:

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

SQL will be generated, but must be modified a little bit (*WHERE clauses added*)

```
class Version20170622165834 extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        // ...

        $this->addSql('
            CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_idx_2_fields ON tbl (field1, field2)
            WHERE field3 IS NULL;
        ');
        $this->addSql('
            CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_idx_3_fields ON tbl (field1, field2, field3)
            WHERE field3 IS NOT NULL;
        ');
    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Execute generated SQL (migrate):

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n
```

Done!

Answer (score 3):

Am also faced the same issue, didn't find any way to resolve it.

Finally added one more varchar column to my table, its value is combination of 3 fields. ex:5_1_0(manually checking and adding 0 for null constraint otherwise constraint Id) and added unique constraint on new column and removed existing constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar case where A was always set, B and C were nullable but one of them always set.

So I had these possibilities:

```
A.  B.   C.
123-null-789
123-456-null
```

I've tried to create a UniqueConstraint as a combination of `A-B-C`, but this didn't work.

What has worked was two UniqueConstraints with the where option:

```
 @ORM\UniqueConstraint(
      name="unique-key-1",
      columns={"a", "b"},
      options={"where": "b IS NOT NULL"}
   ),
 @ORM\UniqueConstraint(
      name="unique-key-2",
      columns={"a", "c"},
      options={"where": "c IS NOT NULL"}
   )
```

That way the unique keys worked for the correct cases.