# Primary key for multiple columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, primary-key, ddl, composite-primary-key

How to provide primary key for multiple column in a single table using PostgreSQL?

Example:

```
Create table "Test" 
(
   "SlNo" int not null primary key,
   "EmpID" int not null, /* Want to become primary key */
   "Empname" varchar(50) null,
   "EmpAddress" varchar(50) null
);
```

Note: I want to make `"EmpID"` also a primary key.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, are you trying to create a single primary key with both columns, or two entirely separate keys?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, Single primary key for both columns.

Comment: Just for the record, so that this Q becomes clear even for mathematically-inclined people: The OP wants to have the pair (SlNo, EmpID) as the primary key.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

There can only be *one* [`PRIMARY KEY` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) per table (spanning one or more columns) - as indicated by the word "primary".
You can have additional [`UNIQUE` constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) (spanning one or more columns).

Short syntax with **"column constraints"**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(
  sl_no  int PRIMARY KEY  -- NOT NULL due to PK
, emp_id int UNIQUE NOT NULL
, ...
);
```

Columns that are (part of) the `PRIMARY KEY` are marked `NOT NULL` automatically. Some like to add a `NOT NULL` constraint explicitly. Redundant, but doesn't hurt.
`UNIQUE` constraints allow null values - unless the column is marked `NOT NULL` explicitly. See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

The same can be achieved with **"table constraints"** - the only syntax option to involve multiple columns. Like a [**multicolumn** `PRIMARY KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS). Now, only the *combination* of columns must be unique, each column can hold duplicates on its own. Minimal syntax:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  sl_no  int  -- NOT NULL due to PK below
, emp_id int  -- NOT NULL due to PK below
, ...
, PRIMARY KEY (sl_no, emp_id)
);
```

Or full syntax with custom constraint name:

```sql
...
, CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sl_no, emp_id)
...
```

"test_pkey" also happens to be the default PK name for a table named "test".

There are a number of optional additional modifiers. Read the manual.

Aside: Use legal, lower-case identifiers in Postgres, so you never have to double-quote. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to specify the name of the primary key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   sl_no int not null,
   emp_id int not null,
   emp_name text,
   emp_addr text,
   constraint pk_test primary key (sl_no, emp_id)
);
```

Source: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-primary-key/

Answer (score 3):

A multi-column primary key can be specified after all columns:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   sl_no int,
   emp_id int,
   emp_name text,
   emp_addr text,
   PRIMARY KEY (sl_no, emp_id)
);
```

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Isn't this case already answered in the answer from Erwin Brandstetter from 2014?