# Postgres - Configure Unique Constraint on values in 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, unique

I am trying to configure unique constraint on the combination on values of 2 columns.

**ExpID1** points to some String 
**ExpID2** points to some other String 
**MatchValue** is the Match Score for the two Strings.

```
Create tbl_A (
   ExpID1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ExpID2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   MatchScore NUMERIC NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ExpID1 , ExpID2));
```

Because the match score between the values against ExpID1 and ExpID2 is going to be the same 
I don't want to store the entry twice.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_A VALUES(1,2, 0.988)
INSERT INTO tbl_A VALUES(2,1, 0.988) -- This should fail because the combination is not unique.
```

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533184/primary-key-for-multiple-column-in-postgresql

Comment: As an alternative to the suggested you can create a check constraint that enforces relationship between id1 and id2. alter table tbl_a add constraint id1LTid2_ck check (expid1<expid2);