# unique_together constraint on multiple columns with NULL values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a database of automotive parts which includes branded & unbranded items. If the brand name is unavailable, the `full_name` is simply `Part.name`, else it is `Brand.name + Part.name`.

How can I define a `unique_together` constraint to ensure uniqueness of `full_name` at database level? The current constraint allows multiple parts with same name if brand name is missing (i.e. `brand_id` `ForeignKey` is `NULL`)

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Part(models.Model);
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.brand_id:
            full_name = '%s %s'.format(self.brand.name, self.name)
        else:
            full_name = self.name
        return full_name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'brand'),)
```

Using : Django 1.6 + PostgreSQL 9.3

P.S. There's an excellent suggestion here to achieve this with SQL. I'm looking for a solution using Django ORM. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/781695

Comment: With django2.2 you can use now the UniqueConstraint and its condition-parameter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to tell django to add that index I'm afraid, `unique_together` only handles simple indexes. However, you can validate at the model layer using the `clean` method, which you should call before saving your model instance (ModelForm instances call it for you):

```
from django.core.validators import ValidationError

class Part(models.Model):

    def clean(self):
        duplicates = Part.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(name=self.name)
        if self.brand:
            duplicates = duplicates.filter(brand=self.brand)
        if duplicates.count():
            raise ValidationError(u'Duplicate part/brand')
```

Ideally you should manually add the index to your Postgres database, using a [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) operation in your migrations.

Comment: Just be aware that this is called by ModelForm, but **not** when `save` is called