# Composite PRIMARY KEY enforces NOT NULL constraints on involved columns

Tags: postgresql, database-design, null, unique, primary-key

This is one strange, unwanted behavior I encountered in Postgres:
When I create a Postgres table with composite primary keys, it enforces NOT NULL constraint on each column of the composite combination.

For example,

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (m_id integer, x_id integer, PRIMARY KEY(m_id, x_id));
```

enforces `NOT NULL` constraint on columns `m_id` and `x_id`, which I don't want!
MySQL doesn't do this. I think Oracle doesn't do it as well.

I understand that `PRIMARY KEY` enforces `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` automatically but that makes sense for single-column primary key. In a multi-column primary key table, the uniqueness is determined by the combination.

Is there any simple way of avoiding this behavior of Postgres? When I execute this:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (m_id integer, x_id integer);
```

I do not get any `NOT NULL` constraints of course. But I would not have a primary key either.

Comment: Well: it is the standard. Imagine two tuples being present, both with `x_id = NULL`. Now, if you wanted to update _only one_ of these, you would not be able to address only one, that would violate 2NF. (all this because: **NULL is not a value**) Note that for the DBMS at ddl-time, there are two choices: either refusing the definition, or converting the key-fields to not-nullable automatically.

Comment: I see what you're saying. 
I am trying to migrate from MySQL to Postgres and hence this inconsistency causes a problem.
Can you elaborate more on "Note that for the DBMS at ddl-time, there are two choices: either refusing the definition, or converting the key-fields to not-nullable automatically."

Comment: It is an illegal definition. So the DBMS can refuse it. Or correct it. (You could compare it to a C-compiler confronted with the definition `int i=1.0;` )

Comment: You are wrong. MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, all have the same exact behaviour as Postgres. No nulls are allowed in columns that are part of the primary key.

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding. Like @ypercube commented: Oracle does not allow NULL values in a PK column: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52cf2/1. Neither does MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce8d4e.

Comment: It's not strange behavior.  A collection of columns that can include NULLS is not, by definition, a candidate key.  This has been part of the relational model since 1970.  If it can't be a candidate key, then it can't be the primary key.  It would be strange if Postgres did *not* enforce it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you *need* to allow NULL values, use a [**`UNIQUE` constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) (or index) instead of a `PRIMARY KEY` (and add a surrogate PK column - I suggest a `serial` or `IDENTITY` column in Postgres 10 or later).

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

A `UNIQUE` constraint allows columns to be NULL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE distributor (
  distributor_id GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, m_id integer
, x_id integer
, UNIQUE(m_id, x_id)  -- !
-- , CONSTRAINT distributor_my_name_uni UNIQUE (m_id, x_id)  -- verbose form
);
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> For the purpose of a unique constraint, null values are not considered equal, unless `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` is specified.

In your case, you could enter something like `(1, NULL)` for `(m_id, x_id)` any number of times without violating the constraint. Postgres does not consider two NULL values *equal* - as per definition in the SQL standard.

If you need to **treat `NULL` values as equal** (i.e. "not distinct") to disallow such "duplicates", I see <strike>two</strike> three (since Postgres 15) options:

#### 0. `NULLS NOT DISTINCT`

This option was added with **Postgres 15** and allows to treat NULL values as "not distinct", so two of them conflict in a unique constraint or index. This is the most convenient option, going forward. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS):

> That means even in the presence of a unique constraint it is possible
> to store duplicate rows that contain a null value in at least one of
> the constrained columns. This behavior can be changed by adding the
> clause `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` ...

Detailed instructions:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

#### 1. Two partial indexes

*In addition* to the `UNIQUE` constraint above:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dist_m_uni_idx ON distributor (m_id) WHERE x_id IS NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dist_x_uni_idx ON distributor (x_id) WHERE m_id IS NULL;
```

But this gets out of hands quickly with more than two columns that can be NULL. See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

#### 2. A multi-column `UNIQUE` index on expressions

Instead of the `UNIQUE` constraint. We need a free default value that is never present in involved columns, like `-1`. Add `CHECK` constraints to disallow it:

```
CREATE TABLE distributor (
   distributor serial PRIMARY KEY
 , m_id integer
 , x_id integer
 , CHECK (m_id <> -1)
 , CHECK (x_id <> -1)
);
```

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX distributor_uni_idx
ON distributor (COALESCE(m_id, -1), COALESCE(x_id, -1));
```

Comment: MySQL behaves the same exact way as Postgres in this aspect. The OP is wrong in his assertions.

Comment: That is a nice (but ugly) workaround. Sigh. @ypercube : could depend on the engine, IIRC. Or the phase of the moon...

Comment: @wildplasser No, it doesn't depend on the engine (at least myisam and innodb, the 2 most common engines.) Perhaps the OP is working on some ancient version of mysql.

Comment: And why is it ugly? The op wants unique constraints and nulls.

Comment: @ypercube: OK, removed the assertion about MySQL, I trust you know its behavior. I know Oracle treats NULL and empty string identically, at least in some contexts, I suspected MySQL would treat two NULL as equal in a UNIQUE constraint, but no it doesn't: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78ddc/1. But Oracle does: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a6db/1 (disappointing for such a big player ...)

Comment: Yes, indeed. And it gets more weird. [Oracle marvels: Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b689c/1). Can you guess what causes this?

Comment: @ypercube: I guess Larry and his friends smoked bad stuff in the late 70s when they started working on their RDBMS. Seriously, seems like all-null values constitute an actual "composite null" that is treated as not equal to another one, while partial NULL values are treated like an empty string in character types, and therefore equal. Wouldn't want *that* ...

Comment: It has nothing to do with strings. It's a side effect of indexes - which do not include rows that have only nulls. If a  row (of the index) has some non-null values, then it is included in the index. The only excuse they may have is that their implementation may predate the SQL standard (no idea if that's true) ;)

Comment: This is an very bad workaround, by changing the constraint to unique and adding a surrogate primary key.

Answer (score 1):

#### In case you want a polymorphic relation

Your table uses column names that indicate that they are probably references to other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (m_id integer, x_id integer);
```

So I think you *probably* are trying to model a polymorphic relation to other tables – where a record in your table `distributors` can refer to one `m` record *xor* one `x` record.

Polymorphic relations are difficult in SQL. The best resource I have seen about this topic is "[Modeling Polymorphic Associations in a Relational Database](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/modeling-polymorphic-associations-in-a-relational-database)". There, four alternative options are presented, and the recommendation for most cases is called "Exclusive Belongs To", which in your case would lead to a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  m_id integer REFERENCES m,
  x_id integer REFERENCES x,
  CHECK (
    ((m_id IS NOT NULL)::integer + (x_id IS NOT NULL)::integer) = 1
  )
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON distributors (m_id) WHERE m_id IS NOT NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON distributors (x_id) WHERE x_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Like other solutions, this uses a surrogate primary key column because primary keys are enforced to not contain `NULL` values in the SQL standard.

This solution adds a 4th option to the three in [@Erwin Brandstetter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643137) for how to avoid the case where "you could enter something like `(1, NULL)` for `(m_id, x_id)` any number of times without violating the constraint." Here, that case is excluded by a combination of two measures:

1. **Partial unique indexes** on each column individually: two records `(1, NULL)` and `(1, NULL)` would not violate the constraint on the second column as `NULL`s are considered distinct, but they would violate the constraint on the first column (two records with value `1`).
2. **Check constraint:** The missing piece is preventing multiple `(NULL, NULL)` records, still allowed because `NULL`s are considered distinct, and anyway because our partial indexes do not cover them to save space and write events. This is achieved by the `CHECK` constraint, which prevents any `(NULL, NULL)` records by making sure that exactly one column is `NULL`.

There's **one difference** though: all alternatives in [@Erwin Brandstetter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643137) allow at least one record `(NULL, NULL)` and any number of records with no `NULL` value in any column (like `(1, 2)`). When modeling a polymorphic relation, you want to disallow such records. That is achieved by the check constraint in the solution above.