# Custom Uniqueness validator for hstore Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, hstore

I would like to perform a uniqueness validation on a hstore field.

When I set is as:

```
class User
  store_accessor :attributes, :foo_attr
  validates :foo_attr, uniqueness: true
end
```

I get `undefined method 'limit' for nil:NilClass`

In a Rails issue [store_accessor and uniqueness validation?](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17954)  user [al2o3cr](https://github.com/al2o3cr) explains:

> validates_uniqueness_of is not going to work in this case - it's
>   expecting a database column named stripe_id. With an Hstore column
>   it's technically possible to perform the required query, but the
>   resulting SQL is only applicable to that storage format and only works
>   on Postgres.
>
> In your case, a custom subclass of
>   ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator with an overridden
>   build_relation would probably be a better choice.

How would you go around creating that custom validator?

I already have a database level uniqueness set up as explained in [Race condition using Postgres hstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740643/race-condition-using-postgres-hstore) all I need now is to make valid? return false on the same foo_attr.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to the trouble of setting up a custom hstore index and writing a custom validation, my first instinct is that maybe you want `foo_attr` to be a column of its own.

As for a custom validation, it's pretty straightforward:

```
validate :foo_attr_uniqueness

def foo_attr_uniqueness
  if self.class.where(foo_attr: foo_attr) # Same foo_attr
               .where.not(id: id)         # On a different record
               .exists?
    errors.add(:foo_attr, 'must be unique')
  end
end
```