# JPA Annotation @Column(insertable=false) is being ignored, why?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want one of the fields to be ignored when called `save()` method. The field is gonna get populated automatically by the database and returned. It should be treated as a read-only field.

I am concerned about `private Timestamp ts;` field:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "time_series", schema = "ms")
@IdClass(Reading.class)
public class Reading implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
   private String sensorName;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ts", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Timestamp ts;

   @Column(name = "reading")
   private Double value;
   ...
```

As you see, I use `insertable = false, updatable = false` are inside the `@Column` annotation, so I'd expect that `ts` is ignored when forming the actual SQL behind the curtain.

```java
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Reading save(Reading r) {        
    return readingRepository.save(r);
}
```

**ReadingRepository** is basically extended Spring's **CrudRepository** which has `save(...)` method.

When I save **Reading** object with `ts=null` I get an error from Postgres:

> ERROR: null value in column "ts" violates not-null constraint

because Spring Data did not actually ignore the **ts** field based **what I see from the log**:

```sql
insert into ms.time_series (ts, name, reading) values (NULL, 'sensor1', 10.0)
```

Clearly, I want the query to be without **ts** like this:

```sql
insert into ms.time_series (name, reading) values ('sensor1', 10.0)
```

#### Why is the field not being ignored?

Now if you ask me whether my database schema is okay I say yes. When I type SQL query in console without the ts everything is fine. I even tried `@Generated` and `@GeneratedValue` annotations. **Name** and **ts** are both forming a primary key for the table, however, the result is the same if I make only one of them a PK or if I add an extra surrogate ID column. Same result...

**Am I overlooking something or is there maybe a bug in the Spring framework??** I am using Spring 5.1.2 and SpringData 2.1.2

Note: If I use `@Transient` annotation that persists the insert query correctly but then the field is being ignored completely even on read/fetch.

Many thanks for any help with this!

Comment: use @Transient annotation on your  Timestamp field.

Comment: If it isn't insertable or updatable how can it be `null`? Also your mapping is weird how can the `@IdClass` be the same as the entity class?

Comment: @M.Deinum I had to add `@IdClass` so that I can have two `@Id`s here. As I mentioned, when I removed that the error still persisted.

Comment: I know what `@IdClass` is for, but it should be a separate class and not point to the entity. Also an `@Id` that isn't generated (you need to specify that) needs to be inserted. So basically your mapping is conflicting. You don't want a generated value, but don't want to insert it as. So hibernate needs to make a decisions.

Comment: @AngadBansode please, read my post, I cannot use `@Transient` because I need to be able to fetch and read that value

Comment: @M.Deinum many thanks! I guess that must be the case. I will try to see if I can fix it by moving it to a different class ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GenericGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html) and [GeneratedValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) in your code.

Add the needed annotation and give values to all other members in Reading class, except ts.

Here some [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator).

Comment: Thank! I tried that and it didn't work, maybe I haven't come up with the right choice permutation yet.

Comment: Anyways, is it a good idea to mix javax.persistence.* org.hibernate.annotations.* annotations together?? GeneratedValue is javax and GenericGenerator is hibernate.

Answer (score -1):

As you say

> I get an error from Postgres

If you check the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/ddl-constraints.html) it states:

> Technically, a primary key constraint is simply a combination of a unique constraint and a not-null constraint.

That's also true for multi-column primary keys (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642835/composite-primary-key-enforces-not-null-constraints-on-involved-columns))

So, if `ts` is part of your primary key in the database (as the `@Id` indicates) it's simply not possible to insert null values in that column.

IMO Hibernate/Spring got nothing to do with that as

```
insert into ms.time_series (ts, name, reading) values (NULL, 'sensor1', 10.0)
```

should be equivalent to

```
insert into ms.time_series (name, reading) values ('sensor1', 10.0)
```

Comment: well if Hibernate/Spring have nothing to do with this, then the SQL query sent should be without the "ts" still. Also I said I tried to make the "ts" not part of the primary key and the error still persisted

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ms.time_series (
 ts TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT ('now'::text)::timestamp(0),
    name VARCHAR(255),
    reading DOUBLE PRECISION,
    PRIMARY KEY(ts, name)
);`
in SQL console I can run a query `insert into ms.time_series (name, reading) values ('sensor1', 10)` no problem

Comment: Why are you creating a timestamp with now, convert that to text to convert that to a timestamp again? What is the reasoning behind that.

Comment: @M.Deinum I copy pasted that from somewhere, I will fix it, but I don't believe it is the cause of the problem. The problem is that Spring/Hibernate is sending an incorrect SQL query which may be either caused by me improperly using the annotations or a bug in the framework itself.

Comment: It isn't an incorrect SQL, the SQL is perfectly valid. Spring has nothing to do with. The problem is the mapping. You want a non-generated ID and don't want to insert it. Hibernate has to make a decisions and decides that it needs to insert the currently assigned value. You need to tell hibernate that it should use a database generated value, else hibernate doesn't know how to handle it. It currently assumes client assigned/generated ids.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right, the Hibernate is confused. I guess I need to play with the `@GeneratedValue` but I don't know how. Whether I set it to AUTO, IDENTITY or TABLE it still doesn't work. Any idea how to set it up properly?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried all I could possibly. All the possible permutations of `@GeneratedValue` along with `@TableGenerator`. I have spent 3 days on this, so I opened this thread also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290636/how-to-set-up-jpa-annotations-to-generate-id-primary-key-on-the-database-level
getting really desperate

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you remove the default value in the database and simply assign ts in your application...

Comment: "it's simply not possible to insert null values in that column" -- correct, but it's possible to _attempt_ to do it, which is an error.  That's what the generated SQL does, and why it's an error.  It's well-formed, but NOT valid!  And definitely not equivalent to the desired statement.  Simple example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hV41cNimtxemj1F6P2HQuE/2

Comment: @MatthewRead: Your "simple example" isn't very fitting, as the "SERIAL" datatype creates an auto-increment column in the table (which of course works), so it got very little to do with the original question ... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5RXdNXrj4B3gxEGKY7x5fu/0 shows that both statements fail for the same reason (and therefore, regarding the outcome are equivalent).

Comment: Your example agrees with me that it is possible to _attempt_ to insert null.  Which, again, is what OP's statement does and is the issue.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5RXdNXrj4B3gxEGKY7x5fu/1 shows that they are _not_ equivalent with a default value, which OP has.

Comment: It's possible to attempt a lot of things :) But yes, with default values (which I overlooked) they're of course not equivalent... point taken.

Comment: @user3732445 i am having the same problem. I am fetching a list from a view so it is a read only. And after adding updatable=false and insertable=false on the field it still calls insert into view. It however doesn't update which is correct. I was excited to see your thread but it seems there was no solution. What did you end up doing? I do not want the insert to be called.