# How to set up JPA annotations to generate ID (Primary Key) on the database level?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's suppose I have a primary key `ts` of type Timestamp. That field is generated automatically on insert into my PostgreSQL table. I want to tell JPA/Hibernate **not to send** or populate that field but just ignore it when the entity is being persisted.

```java
...

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "mygenerator")
@TableGenerator(name = "mygenerator", table = "ms.time_series")
@Column(name = "ts", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
private Timestamp ts; 
...
```

I cannot get it to work. It looks like the `@Id` and `@Columns(insertable = false, updatable = false)` don't work together, that setting is being ignored and the framework is trying to modify or send the value in anyways.

I am using the latest Spring 5 and Spring Data 2.1.2 with Hibernate. Database is PostgreSQL.

#### Any idea what can be wrong? How can I set up the annotations properly for this to work?