# JPA - multi-column unique constraint with null value

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, postgresql-9.1

```
I have an entity like this
@Entity
class Foo {
    long id;

     String name;

     Double parent_id;

     Double super_parent_id;

}
```

And i want this 3 column as a unique key like this :

```
@Table(name = "FOO", uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name", "parent_id","super_parent_id"})
})
```

but this 2 column ( parent_id , super_parent_id ) are nullable so if i have this data

```
name        parent_id      super_parent_id
my_name        1              NULL
my_name        1              NULL
```

the `jpa` see this two rows difference and it's logical because NULL IS difference from NULL

but i want them to be validate as same row

Any suggestion ?.
Thanks

Comment: The constraint is a database constraint - you are hitting issues with SQL specification not JPA.  You can handle it with java by making it the primary key rather then the long id, but I'm guessing you are looking for a postgress or SQL solution.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns

Comment: thanks for the Clarification , i was think that is a jpa specification , the solution work for me