# Unique constraint with null columns (Hibernate, PostgreSQL)

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, unique

I have class like Clazz

```
    @Table(
    name="tablename", 
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(
                          name= "uniqueColumn_deleted_uk",
                          columnNames={"myuniquecolumn", "deleted"}
                         )

    )
 public class Clazz {

     @Column(name = "deleted")
     private LocalDateTime deleted;
}
```

deleted is nullable, PosgreSQL creates unique index like

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueColumn_date_uk ON public.tablename (short_code_3, deleted);
```

and it allows insert duplicate myuniquecolumn when deleted is NULL.

How prevent this?

I want have non duplicates when deleted is null.

Answer (score 2):

You should create two partial unique indexes

```
create unique index on public.tablename (short_code_3, deleted) where deleted is not null;
create unique index on public.tablename (short_code_3) where deleted is null;
```

(I don't know how to do it in your ORM).

Comment: I came-up with a trigger function, but this works better.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because null is never = null.

Read more about null values in SQL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

If you want to have the deleted column in the unique index you must provide a default value for that column.

Answer (score 0):

Tow partial indexes like [klin provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40933440/939860) are best practice up to Postgres 14.

**Postgres 15** adds **`NULLS NOT DISTINCT`** for this purpose:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_idx ON public.tbl (short_code_3, deleted) NULLS NOT DISTINCT;
```

See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)