# Unique Constraint Ignored by Null

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.6, and have an issue where I am using `jsonb_populate_recordset`.

I created an `UNIQUE` constraint on the table, but I am able to bypass this when performing an `INSERT` with null values.

Is there was a way to force the unique constraint to keep only 1 record, even if it has `null` values, and not allow duplicates afterward?

Here is a quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
    person_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    person_name TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT unq_person UNIQUE(person_name)
);

INSERT INTO person (person_name) VALUES ('Frank');

CREATE TABLE locations(
  location_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  city TEXT,
  state TEXT,
  address TEXT,
  address_country TEXT,
  postal_code TEXT,
  person_id INTEGER REFERENCES person(person_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT unq_location UNIQUE(city, state, address, address_country, postal_code, person_id)
);
```

In this example, city and address are `null` (but theoretically, they could all be `null`, or any combination of record properties).

Every time I run the following query, a new record gets inserted. I don't want more than one of these records.

```
INSERT INTO locations (city, state, address, address_country, postal_code, person_id)
SELECT city, state, address, address_country, postal_code, person_id
FROM jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::locations, '[{"city": null, "address": null, "address_country": "USA", "state": "NY", "person_id": 1, "postal_code": "10001"}]'::jsonb)
```

How can I only allow 1 record, and not multiple when inserting a `JSONB` object into Postgres?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson - based on that, I would create 5 partial indexes?

Comment: @VaoTsun - That suggested solution does not appear to work: `ALTER TABLE locations
ADD CONSTRAINT unq_location UNIQUE(COALESCE(city, state, address, address_country, postal_code, person_id))` gives a syntax error. Did I miss something?

Comment: @VaoTsun - Still having syntax error when doing `CONSTRAINT unq_location UNIQUE(coalesce(city, null),coalesce(state, null),coalesce(address,null))`. Does `COALESCE` work with `UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS`?

Comment: @unseen_damage try `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_location on locations (
   coalesce(city,'null')
 , coalesce("state",'null')
 , coalesce(address,'null')
 , coalesce(address_country,'null')
 , coalesce(postal_code,'null')
 , coalesce(person_id,0)
 )
;
`

Comment: @VaoTsun - That solution did not work

Answer (score 0):

To your existing query:

```
insert into locations
(fields)
select values
from etc
```

add this filter

```
where not exists 
(select 1
from locations l2
where locations.person_id = l2.person_id
)
```

It has nothing to do with null values.

Comment: I added that `WHERE` clause to the end of my `INSERT` statement, and got an error - `ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "locations"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "l2".
Character: 380
` Did I miss something?