# How to use multiple "unique index inferences" in a Postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, insert, sql-insert

In a Postgresql 9.6 DB, there is a existing table named `X` that has four columns, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` with indices setup like this:

```
"uidx_a_b" UNIQUE, btree (a, b) WHERE c IS NULL AND d IS NULL
"uidx_a_c" UNIQUE, btree (a, b, c) WHERE c IS NOT NULL AND d IS NULL
"uidx_a_d" UNIQUE, btree (a, b, c, d) WHERE c IS NOT NULL AND d IS NOT NULL
```

I don't know why this was done as it was done by someone long gone and before I had to modify it.

I am trying to get the syntax correct for specifying all three of these in an ON CONFLICT statement.  I tried every variation I could think of all with error.  The [Postgresql Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html) indicates this is possible, specifically the `[, ...]` described in the `conflict_target` here:

```
( { index_column_name | ( index_expression ) } [ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [, ...] )
```

Also, this [blog](http://pgeoghegan.blogspot.com/2015/10/avoid-naming-constraint-directly-when.html) from one of the committers says so.  Finally, I looked at [this unit test for the functionality](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/test/regress/sql/insert_conflict.sql;h=ba2b66bdb6739c120b93f460f262e73aa7ec1706;hb=168d5805e4c08bed7b95d351bf097cff7c07dd65) again to no avail!  Having thus given up, I am turning to SO to seek help.

This is what I believe is the closest syntax I tried that should work:

```
ON CONFLICT (
((a, b) WHERE c IS NULL AND d IS NULL),
((a, b, c) WHERE c IS NOT NULL AND d IS NULL),
((a, b, c, d) WHERE release_id IS NOT NULL AND d IS NOT NULL)
)
```

However this fails with:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
```

While I am open to suggestions to improve the `design` of those indices, I really want to know if there is a valid syntax for specifying the ON CONFLICT clause as it seems there should be!

Comment: `on conflict` only accepts a **single** condition

Comment: Dirty data-hack: make the {c,d} columns not NULLable and use a special value (-1 or 0) to indicate NULLness. Now you only need the unique index on (a,b,c,d) . The case with c IS NULL and d NOT IS NULL should be handled specially.

Comment: @joop I think that is a pretty good idea - might improve performance too, would certainly save some data as these actual tables are large!  Still want to know about the syntax though....

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I updated the question to indicate where it seems to say multiple conditions ARE supported.  Maybe they aren't though?

Comment: Think before you act: if the {c,d} columns are FK's (which I suspect) you'll also need dummy-rows in the referred tables. **Plus:** additional code to suppress/handle these in queries.

Comment: Just to clarify why these multiple indexes were needed, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8289100/157957 Basically, a normal unique constraint will allow any number of NULLs, because they aren't considered equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I am referring to the syntax description from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html):

> `ON CONFLICT [ conflict_target ] conflict_action`
>
> where `conflict_target` can be one of:
>
> `( { index_column_name | ( index_expression ) }`
>               `[ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [, ...] ) [ WHERE index_predicate ]`
>       `ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name`

`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` allows only a single `conflict_target`.
The `[, ...]` means that more than one column or expression can be specified (to indicate a single condition), like this:

```
ON CONFLICT (col1, (col2::text), col3)
```

Moreover, if it is a partial index, the `WHERE` condition must be implied by `index_predicate`.

**So what can you do?**

You can follow the advice from @joop and find a value that cannot occur in columns `c` and `d`.

Then you can replace your three indexes with:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON x (a, b, coalesce(c, -1), coalesce(d, -1));
```

The `conflict_target` would then become:

```
ON CONFLICT (a, b, coalesce(c, -1), coalesce(d, -1))
```