# Unique constraint on JSONB null field

Tags: postgresql, database-design, null, unique-constraint, jsonb

Let me use a simple sample to describe my question. Say I have a table t that has only two fields, auto 'id', and a jsonb typed 'info' field:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
  ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  info jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

'info' might have fields 'a', 'b', 'c' as well as some other fields. Field 'c' might be null, and I want to (a, b, c) to be unique, so I created a unique index on them:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_abc ON t (
  (info ->> 'a'), (info ->> 'b'), (info ->> 'c')
);
```

But then I realized that, if 'c' is null, this unique constraint doesn't work at all. For example, I can insert multiple rows of:

```
insert into t(info) values('{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}')
```

or

```
insert into t(info) values('{"a": "a1", "b": "b1", "c": null}')
```

My current solution is to anyway give "c" a value, if "c" is null, then I set "null":

```
insert into t(info) values('{"a": "a1", "b": "b1", "c": "null"}')
```

this way will trigger the unique constraint if I run the insert twice. But I feel this is just a workaround, I wonder if there is a better to solution to allow the unique constraint to work even if field "c" is null.

Comment: BSON? You mean `jsonb`, right? And please remember to always declare your Postgres version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just the one key that might have a NULL value, partial indexes would be an efficient solution, like outlined here:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

A more general (less efficient) solution is to use [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_abc ON t (
   COALESCE(info ->> 'a', 'NULL')
 , COALESCE(info ->> 'b', 'NULL')
 , COALESCE(info ->> 'c', 'NULL')
);
```

This way you fold actual `NULL` values and the string 'NULL' (arbitrary example) to the same value. Much like you already do, but you don't need to mess with original column values.

I would also consider extracting involved keys from the `jsonb` document as regular Postgres columns (redundantly or not) to have the full arsenal of relational tools at your disposal: (`NOT NULL`) constraints, default values, etc. Faster, too.

Comment: This did not work for me: `COALESCE(info ->> 'a', 'NULL')` i had to change it to `COALESCE(info ->> 'a', NULL)` then it worked. Thanks for the example nonetheless, it was very helpful.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi: This is a misunderstanding. The `COALESCE` wrapper in `COALESCE(info ->> 'a', NULL)` is a no-op (does nothing). The whole point here is to replace `NULL` values with a non-null value, so the `UNIQUE` constraint kicks in. Follow the link above for more explanation.

Comment: Maybe for OP's example, for mine, i want to ignore it if it is not there.

Comment: Not sure about your objective, but `COALESCE(info ->> 'a', NULL)` can *always* be replaced with just `info ->> 'a'`.