# How to ensure uniqueness with NULL values in cockroach DB

Tags: indexing, cockroachdb, partial-index

I have a table of accounts which generates unique keys with a sequence. It is used to generate unique identities for accounts and account/user pairs.

I tried the following from pgsql:

```
CREATE INDEX ON accounts (account_id, user_id) WHERE user_id IS NULL;
```

and

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON accounts (account_id, COALESCE(user_id, ''));
```

But both cases are not supported in cockroach.

Is there another way of ensuring uniqueness with NULL values?

I also have a different UNIQUE index on `user_id` to allow unique IDs to be generated for users without an account.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do something like create a [computed column](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/computed-columns.html) and then use that in an index:

```
alter table accounts add column user_null int null as (coalesce(user_id, 0));
create unique index on accounts (account_id, user_null);
```

Comment: Note this answer is definitely not practical without making the pseudo-column to be computed with [VIRTUAL](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/computed-columns) keyword and that [NOT VISIBLE](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-table#not-visible-property) can be used to hide such an auxiliary column from wildarg resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

The CockroachDB already supports creating [indices by computed expressions](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/expression-indexes) but still [doesn't support](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9827) [unique indices by nullable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns).

So an alternative workaround for partial uniqueness by only a subset of records non-nullable by one of the columns can be to coalesce to an alternative unique group of columns like this:

```
create unique index if not exists some_table_partial_id_semi_unique_index
    on some_table (coalesce(partial_id, a_column || '_' || b_column));

-- double-check that the index is really used:
explain select * from some_table where partial_id = '13';
```