# PostgreSQL. I need a hierarchical table to have a constraint so no node could have the same name on the same level

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a hierarchical table with duplicate names on the same level. Example -

```
user (int id, string name, int parent_id)
1, Sam, null
2, Mike, 1
3, Mike, 1
4, Mike, 1
```

I need to make them like this

```
1, Sam, null
2, Mike#1, 1
3, Mike#2, 1
4, Mike#3, 1
```

And somehow add constraint. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I needed to rename duplicates on the same level. Even in root directory where parent_id is null. This code will do

```
 update user user_update set name = name || '#' || (
 select user_count_ids.number
   from (
        select user_row_count.id id,  row_number() over (order by user_row_count.id) number
        from user user_row_count
        where user_update.name = user_row_count.name and user_update.parent_id is not distinct from user_row_count.parent_id
   ) as user_count_ids
   where user_count_ids.id = org_update.id
 )
 where (
       select count(*) > 1
       from user user_count
       where user_update.name = user_count.name and user_update.parent_id is not distinct from user_count.parent_id
 );
```

Then I needed some sort of constraint. Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/5292928 I added this code

```
create unique index unique_name_parentId_when_parentId_is_not_null
   on user (name, parent_id)
   where parent_id is not null;
create unique index unique_name_when_parentId_is_null
   on user (name)
   where parent_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `row_number()` to generate those numbers in the sequence and `COUNT` analytic function to check whether or not to use sequence numbers

```
SELECT id,
       CONCAT(name,
                  CASE
                     WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(
                          PARTITION BY name
                     ) > 1 THEN --multiple names exist?
                      '#' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                          PARTITION BY name
                          ORDER BY id )
                  END
       ) AS name, --else defaults to null (for single ones).
       parent_id
FROM t
ORDER BY id;
```

It is not clear when you say "*I need a hierarchical table*", if you want to simply select them or create a new table. I would recommend you not to create another table simply to store mostly those same values, just create a `VIEW` instead using the above query as the base.

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=09716aca1119ce0caa36894b096792e0)

Comment: Thank you) but i needed to change names in db.