# How to create composite UNIQUE constraint with nullable columns?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, typeorm

Let's say I have a table with several columns `[a, b, c, d]` which can all be nullable. This table is managed with Typeorm.
I want to create a unique constraint on `[a, b, c]`. However this constraint does not work if one of these column is NULL. I can insert for instance `[a=0, b= 1, c=NULL, d=0]` and `[a=0, b= 1, c=NULL, d=1]`, where `d` has different values.

With raw SQL, I could set multiple partial constraints ([Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns)) however, in my case, the unique constraint is on 10 columns. It seems absurd to set a constraint for every possible combination...

I could also create a sort of hash function, but this method does not seem proper to me?

Does Typeorm provide a solution for such cases?

Comment: Is there any value that can (or will) never appear in those columns (e.g. `-999999`)

Comment: From what you are describing, the unique constraint should be on a, b, c, _and_ d.  Why would the value of d have anything to do with the current unique constraint?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen To be more precise, I'm registering "prices" entities. In my case, `d` would be the price and `a, b, c` would be meta information and would stand for a unique identifier for the price. If I insert [a='US', b=NULL, c='USD', d=1000], I want this price to be updated if I insert [a='US', b=NULL, c='USD', d=500] later. So I can't put the unique constraint on `a, b, c, d`.

@a_horse_with_no_name Indeed there are values which will never appear. However I think it's much cleaner to keep NULL for data which are meant to be unfilled instead of putting a custom predefined value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have values that can never appear in those columns, you can use them as a replacement in the index:

```
create unique index on the_table (coalesce(a,-1), coalesce(b, -1), coalesce(c, -1));
```

That way `NULL` values are treated the same inside the index, without the need to use them in the table.

If those columns are `numeric` or `float` (rather than `integer` or `bigint`) using `'-Infinity'` might be a better substitution value.

---

There is a drawback to this though:

This index will however not be usable for query on those columns unless you also use the coalesce() expression. So with the above index a query like:

```
select *
from the_table
where a = 10
  and b = 100;
```

would **not** use the index. You would need to use the same expressions as used in the index itself:

```
select *
from the_table
where coalesce(a, -1) = 10
  and coalesce(b, -1) = 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @a_horse_with_no_name, it should work. On the principle, I still think there should be a way to do that without putting default not null values, but based on what I've read, I feel like I'll have to adopt a solution like yours  :)