# How to create unique constraint with nullable field in TypeORM?

Tags: typeorm

How to create unique constraint with nullable field in TypeORM?

I used postgresql12, node v12.22.7.

Is it better to create a separate raw query?

Without a migration tool?

If I use a raw query, can I use it like the address below?

[How to create composite UNIQUE constraint with nullable columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211283/how-to-create-composite-unique-constraint-with-nullable-columns/59213265#59213265)

Here is my code example.

```js
@Entity('users')
@Unique('username-unique',['username', 'deletedAt'])
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ length: 100 })
  username: string

  @Column({ length: 100 })
  name: string

  // sha256
  @Exclude()
  @Column({ type: 'bytea', select: false})
  password: Buffer

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
    type: 'timestamp with time zone'
  })
  lastLoginAt: Date | null

  @OneToMany(() => RoleBindingEntity, (roleBinding) => roleBinding.user, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  roleBinding: RoleBindingEntity[]

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp with time zone',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
  })
  createdAt: Date

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp with time zone',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
  })
  updatedAt: Date

  @DeleteDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp with time zone'
    nullable: true,
  })
  deletedAt: Date
}
```

Comment: Surprised this hasn't been answered... :S

Answer (score -1):

You can set nullable field unique

```
@Column({ nullable: true, unique: true })
checking_data: string;
```

[image]

[image]

#### Migration that I executed for this

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "file_store" ADD "checking_data" character varying`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "file_store" ADD CONSTRAINT "UQ_ab4f7e345fd08fb9611479b4cee" UNIQUE ("checking_data")`);
    }
```