# UPSERT into table with distinct null in unique columns

Tags: postgresql, database-design, upsert, unique-index

I have to upsert into a table of the form:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  col1 varchar
, col2 varchar
, col3 varchar
, col4 varchar
)
```

The condition is that `(col1, col2, col3)` should be unique, and it should allow distinct null values.

I have tried using a unique index. I think we need to have a constraint as we need to upsert into the table. But using the below index is slow while upserting into the table:

```sql
create unique index idx on test_table (
    coalesce(col1, 'null')
  , coalesce(col2, 'null')
  , coalesce(col3, 'null')
   );
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "using the below index is slow"? Slower than what?

Comment: If it is slow as you say, can you also `EXPLAIN` the query and add the query plan into your question? Otherwise it is highly unlikely you will get any decent answer here

Comment: What is "allow distinct null values" trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Since Postgres 15, a plain unique index with the added clause `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` implements your requirement. You don't need the more expensive functional index on `COALESCE` expressions any more:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON test_table(col1,col2,col3) NULLS NOT DISTINCT;
```

It simplifies and accelerates the connected use of `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE ...` (vulgo "UPSERT").
It also removes the ambiguity of the replacement value 'null'.
See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)