# Unique index on expressions not recognized for UPSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, constraints, upsert

I did this to solve the problem regarding having null values in 2 columns for a unique constraint in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uc_column1_column2_column3_column4 ON schema.table
(column1, column2, COALESCE(column3, '0'), COALESCE(column4,'0'));
```

See here: [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns)

But now I have an other problem because using index instead of constraint I have the error:

> there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

when I do this SQL request:

```
INSERT INTO table
        (column1,column2, column3, column4, columnA, columnB, columnC) 
        VALUES (1,2,3,4,A,B,C)
ON CONFLICT (column1,column2, column3, column4) 
DO UPDATE SET column1= EXCLUDED.column1
RETURNING *
```

Note: I do get the correct constraint error without the "on conflict" line.

Comment: On conflict (column1, column2, COALESCE(column3, '0'), COALESCE(column4,'0'))

Comment: Be so kind as to start with your core table definition `CREATE TABLE ...` and your version of Postgres. And about `DO UPDATE SET column1= EXCLUDED.column1`  .. consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860

Comment: Thanks you Cetin. It works as expected this way.

Thanks Erwin. I will have a deeper look to avoid `DO UPDATE SET column1=EXCLUDED.column1`

. On my first try `DO NOTHING`  returns nothing...

Answer (score 0):

If the expression index with `COALESCE(column3, '0')` does not lead to conflicts between `NULL` and `0`, you might as well define `column3` as `column3 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`(guessing the data type) to begin with. Same for `column4`. That would remove all complications.

While you (have to) work with that expression index, your "conflict target" has to match the definition of the unique index, like Cetin suggested:

```sql
INSERT INTO table
       (column1, column2, column3, column4, columnA, columnB, columnC) 
VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, A, B, C)
ON     CONFLICT (column1, column2, COALESCE(column3, '0'), COALESCE(column4,'0')) DO UPDATE
SET    column1 = EXCLUDED.column1
RETURNING *;
```

Since you are working with a `UNIQUE INDEX` and not a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, you cannot just supply the constraint name instead and must go the route of "unique index inference". Or, as [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) puts it:

> *`conflict_target`* can perform unique index inference. When performing inference, it consists of one or more
> ***`index_column_name`*** columns and/or ***`index_expression`*** expressions, and an optional ***`index_predicate`***. All
> ***`table_name`*** unique indexes that, without regard to order, contain exactly the *`conflict_target`*-specified columns/expressions
> are inferred (chosen) as arbiter indexes.

Aside:

`DO UPDATE SET column1= EXCLUDED.column1` never changes anything by definition. It's still costly as it writes a new row version. Probably in use to always return a row. Typically, there are cheaper solutions. See:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)