# Unique constraint for certain value

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique

I have a table in a PostgreSQL DB like this to represent a booking system for office desks. Employees can book one desk (`seat_id`) per day.

| ID | Booked_Date | Seat_ID | Employee_ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-08 | 10C | id1 | booked |
| 2 | 2022-07-08 | 20C | id2 | cancelled |

How to make a unique constraint with multiple column (`booked_date`, `seat_id`, and `status` with value 'booked') to guarantee that no more than one employee can book the same seat for the same day?

Note: employees can cancel the seat that they have booked and the row stays in the table with changed status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) `UNIQUE` index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON booking_tbl (booked_date, seat_id)
WHERE status = 'booked';
```

Related:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)