# Adding unique constraint for null column returns error

Tags: postgresql, null, unique-constraint

I am trying to add a unique constraint to an existing table in Postgres on a null column named `personnel_id`. Most of the records have null `personnel_id`. Here's how I do it:

```
ALTER TABLE "myschema"."mytable" ADD UNIQUE NULLS not distinct ("personnel_id");
```

And I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  could not create unique index "mytable_personnel_id_key"
> DETAIL:  Key (personnel_id)=() is duplicated.
> ```

My Postgres version is:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg120+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message actually reports a conflict for **empty strings**, i.e. two or more instances of `''` - not the same as `null`!  For conflicting null values you would see:

> ERROR:  Key (personnel_id)=(null) is duplicated.

But you get:

> ERROR:  Key (personnel_id)=() is duplicated.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qnz_3bDE)

You need version Postgres 15 or newer to use the `NULLS [NOT] DISTINCT` feature. See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

Also:

> psql (PostgreSQL) 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg120+1)

[psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is **not** PostgreSQL. It's the default interactive terminal and is not necessarily in line with the Postgres version. Check your Postgres version with `SELECT version();` while being connected.

Modern versions of psql **also** show the Postgres version on connection **if** it disagrees.

Example:
When starting psql 16.1 connecting to a Postgres 16.1 DB:

> psql (16.1 (Ubuntu 16.1-1.pgdg20.04+1))

When connecting to a DB cluster with different Postgres version:

> psql (16.1 (Ubuntu 16.1-1.pgdg20.04+1), server 14.10 (Ubuntu 14.10-1.pgdg20.04+1))

The second part of the display is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it is NULL values you are seeing, not empty strings. Two empty strings are always equal.

If you specify `NULLS NOT DISTINCT`, PostgreSQL treats two NULL values as not distinct, so you will get an error.

If you want NULLs to be distinct, that is, if you want several NULL values to be present in the unique column, use `NULLS DISTINCT`:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable ADD UNIQUE NULLS DISTINCT (personnel_id);
```

Comment: It gives me the exact error :/

Comment: No, it doesn't. You must have made a typo.

Comment: No, it's empty strings.